# Display results from two Custom Post Types in page template

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, rewrite-rules

What I have is

1. Created a new page with slug `monuments`
2. Created a template file at my theme's folder that will show all records with post_type `monument`.

[UPDATE]
3.I forgot to mention that each custom post type "monument" has a "city" parent
[/UPDATE]

What I want to do is, in that same file, to add a list of cities links, and when clicking on any of the cities, it will display only the monuments of that city.

I already have a custom post type `city`.

The URL I want it to display, when clicking on a city's link, is

```
http://example.com/monuments/city-slug
```

Is that possible with `add_rewrite_rule`?

Comment: Unless there's more than you describe, it sounds to me like `city` should be a taxonomy. If you did that, what you're asking is very simple, see [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks) for details.

Comment: No, city is a custom post type. I think that add_rewrite_rule might do the trick. But I don't understand yet the whole procedure.

Comment: I forgot to mention that each custom post type "monument" has a "city" parent. I have included that part in my question.

Comment: Sorry that this was unclear, I was suggesting that you consider _making `city` a taxonomy_. Otherwise, you'll need to do something like here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99378/rewrite-custom-post-type-urls-adding-meta-box-values/

Comment: I see that there are alot of things I need to learn. I have also made some big mistakes, like giving at the CPT "monument" slug "monuments" which is the same slug that the page monuments has... We can just leave it as it is, and when I have more time for reading I'll come back with it. Thank you @Matthew