# Custom Post Type URL Rewrite's

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, urls

I am going to try and sum up what I am trying to achieve...

Basically I have a custom post type called 'marketing_list' which will have custom fields holding information relating to marketing lists available for purchase.

Each marketing list will belong to a category (custom taxonomy).

So currently my URL's look like this:

- `/marketing-lists` -> archive page
- `/marketing-lists/post-slug` -> single marketing lists entry
- `/marketing-lists/category/category-slug` -> custom taxonomy

What I want to achieve is:

- `/marketing-lists` -> archive page but editable within the admin in
  case the client wants to update text, like a Page.
- `/marketing-lists/category-slug` -> custom taxonomy
- `/marketing-lists/category-slug/post-slug` -> single entry

On top of that I would like to create some additional pages which have a base of `/marketing-lists` i.e

- `/marketing-lists/consumer-marketing-lists` -> single page
- `/marketing-lists/business-marketing-lists` -> single page

Is this at all possible? Perhaps their is a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The bulk of your question is fairly easy and has been covered here many times before. I also gave a talk at WordCamp Portland on the topic, which you can [watch, download slides, code, etc. here](http://boyn.es/2013/08/10/wcpdx/).

The last part of your question,

> On top of that I would like to create some additional pages which have a base of /marketing-lists i.e
>
> /marketing-lists/consumer-marketing-lists -> single page /marketing-lists/business-marketing-lists -> single page

... is a little trickier. ***If there will only be a few and they won't often change***, you have two options that I can see:

1. Add specific rewrite rules to the top of the stack to address them
2. Make them taxonomy terms (that you never use as taxonomy terms) and leverage the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to do with them as you please.

Personally, I'd go with #1. If you do, your code may look something like this,

```
function wpse_119673_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'marketing-lists/(consumer-marketing-lists|business-marketing-lists)/?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_119673_rewrite_rules' );
```

See [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) for reference.

If, on the other hand, **you'll have many of these pages and you need to create them on a whim**, it becomes significantly more difficult. Essentially, you'd then have a significant rewrite conflict for which you'd need to account in every matching query. [Here's another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114723/removing-base-slug-from-hierarchical-custom-post-type/116064#116064) which is very different from yours, but where I account for a rewrite conflict (search for "check_rewrite_conflicts") in my answer. In that answer, on every query where the "state" is present, I'm checking to see if that should actually be a page. It's an additional database query, and I would advise against it.

Answer (score 0):

The problematic part of permalink structure you asking for is for permalinks like

```
/marketing-lists/{$something}/
```

where sometimes `$something` should be a category, sometimes a page slug.

So, to make it works you should run a database query to know what `$something` is and that will slow down performance

After that, if the url `example.com/marketing-lists/viral-marketing` and you have a page with slug `viral-marketing` and a category with slug `viral-marketing` what WordPress should show, the page or the category archive?

Even if run a db query, you'll find a page *and* a category with that slug, so who *win*?

Moreover, using standard WordPress rewrite rules your work will be very hard... because a lot of conflict will happen.

I develop a plugin, [Clever Rules](http://rules.zoomlab.it/) can help you a lot for the task, but - again - with no db query is impossible say if the part just after `/marketing-lists/` is a a page slug or a category...

Using that plugin this code should works, but it require a db query and in case of conflict the page slug will win:

```
/*
 * Plugin Name: My Custom Rules
 */

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'register_my_rules');
add_filter('skip_clever_rule', 'rule_pages_for_pages', 20, 3);

function register_my_rules() {

    if ( ! function_exists('register_clever_rule') ) return;

    $args = array( 'id' => 'rule_pages','route' => '/marketing-lists/%s');
    register_clever_rule( $args )->query('pagename=[0]')->priority(1);

    $args = array( 'id' => 'rule_cats','route' => '/marketing-lists/%s');
    register_clever_rule( $args )->query('category_name=[0]')->priority(2);

    $args = array( 'id' => 'rule_singles','route' => '/marketing-lists/%s/%s/');
    register_clever_rule( $args )->query('name=[1]');

}

function rule_pages_for_pages( $skip, $rule, $pieces ) {
  if ( $rule['args']['id'] === 'rule_pages' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $pages = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish'");
    if ( ! in_array( $pieces[1], $pages ) ) $skip = true;
  }
  return $skip;
}
```

Note that that code goes in a **plugin** and can't work in themes.

Comment: Thanks, your plugin looks interesting. I'll give it a try.