# Pagination for blog posts reloading same page

Tags: wp-query, permalinks, pagination

**Symptoms**

Visiting /blog/ loads the first 10 posts, as expected.

Visiting /blog/page/2/ (and onward) loads the new URL but with the same 10 posts. Nothing changes but the URL.

**Setup Details**

Custom Permalink Structure: `/blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`

Static Posts Page: "Blog" (slug of 'blog')

I'm using `home.php` to displays posts with the following markup:

```
<?php
/**
 * The archive for blog posts 
*/

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="container">

            <section id="content" class="blog"> 

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'blog-index' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </section>

            <?php get_sidebar( 'blog' ); ?>

            <div class="pagination">
                <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I've checked for plugin conflicts and I am running a relatively minimalistic setup. I'm using **WP-PageNavi** to generate the pagination.

I've also tried renaming the /blog/ page to 'blog2' with the thought that there might be a permalink conflict - same result. /blog2/page/2/ loads the same first 10 posts.

Any ideas what might be the cause here?

Comment: Does `/blog/?paged=2` bring you to the second page of posts? If it doesn't work, then there is something screwing up the global `WP_Query` object. If it does work, then something is screwed up with the permalinks.

Comment: /blog/?paged=2 does not work. Any recommendations on debugging `WP_Query`?

Comment: Hmmm. Nothing sticks out as to why there would such an issue. At this point I would start disabling plugins and reverting back to one of WordPress' core themes to see if one them is creating a conflict.

Comment: You may also want to do a debug dump to see what the page is being set to: `var_dump( $wp_query );`.

Comment: I've done some additional investigating and found out that the issue is related to my use of a custom class that strips out the "base slug" for a hierarchical post type. Here's referenced question and the code I'm using to do the stripping: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114723/removing-base-slug-from-hierarchical-custom-post-type

Comment: You should add your last comment as an [edit] to your question. Most people don't read comments, like me, I accidentally saw the comment :-)

Comment: Am I mistaken or has the problem you are having nothing to do with method the pagination links are generated? You might want to clarify that, because the answers are focusing on that. Additionally, can you confirm that the pagination works correctly, if you are not using the »strip out base slug«-code you mentioned? Furthermore, does the blog page show posts from the post type `post` or your `CPT` or both? Might be valuable to know. In short, it's probably a good idea to [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/135088/edit) your question with the additional information needed.

Comment: I still don't get it why someone places a bounty on his own question and then simply abandons it, or just simply ignores/refuses to give proper details when asked for it by someone willing to help. Well, at the end of day, it is your reputation, waste it as you wish

Comment: Closing as too localized as there never was any update to the question nor a comment to any of the answers. The real problem is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) );

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    // more stuff here
endwhile;

wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) );

wp_reset_postdata();
```

try this code and also increase the size of show posts in SETTINGS->Reading->Blog pages show at most 10 to 50 or 100, hope so  it will help you.

Comment: Never change the main query for a custom query. You are creating more problems that actually solving the original problem

Comment: then follow this link it will help you [http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html]

Comment: [Read here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using **WP-PageNavi** for number based pagination. WordPress offer a way to accomplish that. BTW here is the full query for you to use in home.php

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div class="container">

        <section id="content" class="blog"> 

            <?php

              if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); } else { $paged = 1; }

              $args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                  'paged' => $paged
              );

              $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

              if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :

                  while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

                      get_template_part( 'content', 'blog-index' );

                  endwhile;

                  if ( $my_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) :
                      $big = 999999999;
                      echo '<div class="pagination">';
                      echo paginate_links( array(
                          'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                          'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                          'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                          'total' => $my_query->max_num_pages
                      ) );
                      echo '</div>';
                  endif;

              else :

                    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

              endif;

              wp_reset_postdata();

            ?>

        </section>

        <?php get_sidebar( 'blog' ); ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code I faced same problem then i implemented this

```
<?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) :?>
    <div class="pagination">
        <?php for ( $i = 1; $i <= $wp_query->max_num_pages; $i ++ ) { 
            $link = $i == 1 ? remove_query_arg( 'pg' ) : add_query_arg( 'pg', $i );
            echo '<a href="' . $link . '"' . ( $i == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '' ) . '>' . $i . '</a>';
        } ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

Using home.php doesn't sound like a good idea, but if it is the only query in the page, you might have to add a couple of things. The following usually works for paginating a static page:

Add:

```
global $paged, $wp_query; 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

But you also have to add one more argument to your query arguments in your template part to enable pagination:

```
'paged'     => $paged
```

Your final code on the template would be:

```
get_header(); ?>

global $paged, $wp_query; 
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="container">

        <section id="content" class="blog"> 

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'blog-index' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </section>

        <?php get_sidebar( 'blog' ); ?>

        <div class="pagination">
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you force the pagination by adding the following code like so:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div class="container">

        <section id="content" class="blog"> 

            <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            query_posts('posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged);
            ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'blog-index' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </section>

        <?php get_sidebar( 'blog' ); ?>

        <div class="pagination">
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Check this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Pagination

Comment: never use `query_posts`, and never run custom queries unnecessary

Comment: @PieterGoosen then Jonathan should add the loaded template part so that we see what is happening there.