# Custom taxonomy template loop

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop

I know that this question is asked numerous but i din't find an answer that suits to me.

Well i'm made some custom post types and some custom taxonomies. I have the custom post type **Products** and linked to it the taxonomy **Product Categories**. When the user is at the *Products* page and clicks on a *Product Category*, i want to show him all the products from this specific category.

The problem is that the product categories will be about 50. Right now the only thing that i found is to put to the wordpress loop this

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'all_products', 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'products' => 'advance' ) ); ?>
```

But this shows the posts only for the advance category. I need a way to automatically takes the category that the user clicked. The dirty way is to make 50 **taxonomy-{slug}.php** files. But i want the clean way. And i can't seem to find it.

I read all the codex about the template hierarchy and specific for the custom taxonomies, and search the half stackexchange but nothing (maybe i've missed something :P ).

I tried to describe my question as clear as i can. If you cant understand something just tell me and i'll try to update the question with more info.

Thank you

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts` to change your `posts_per_page`

Comment: just this? and i should take out the `'products' => 'advance'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I read you question is that you need 12 posts per page in this taxonomy regardless of the current term been displayed.

This can be easily done with [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). You should never change the main query for a custom query on archive pages. Have a read on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) I've recently done on this subject.

Use the [`is_tax()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) conditional to target the taxonomy page and also see the parameters

Add this to functions.php. You can also only use one taxonomy.php for all terms, no need to make 50 others

```
function custom_ppp( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_tax() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '12' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_ppp' );
```

**EDIT**

In taxonomy.php, change this

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'all_products', 'pre_get_posts' => 12, 'products' => 'advance' ) ); ?> 

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> 
    //content 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

back to just this

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
   //content
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Php noob here! I included your code to my theme's functions.php. What i need to modify right now in taxonomy.php? Right now is something like this
`<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'all_products', 'pre_get_posts' => 12, 'products' => 'advance' ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?> 
//content 
<?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: Change it back to the main loop as it originally was

Comment: My pleasure, glad you solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

This is what i am using for **Custom Post Type** `health` and **Custom Taxonomy** `health-category` also fixes the pagination.

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$q = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
     get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) => get_query_var( 'term' ),
    'paged' => $paged
]);
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $q;

if ( $q->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post();

        // post content goes here..

    endwhile;
endif;

// Reset postdata
wp_reset_postdata();

// pagination goes here..

// Reset main query object
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is loosely related to "faceted search", but you aren't quite searching. :)

In a nutshell you would need to:

1. Communicate information about "selected" taxonomy to the page, this might be done with GET query or [rewrite endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint)
2. Generate links (or whatever interface you have) accordingly
3. Adjust main query (!) of the page via `pre_get_posts`, changing queries in template you will very likely hit pagination issues