# Listing child terms of parent term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pagination, terms

I'm using the following code to generate a list of only the child terms within my taxonomy. What I'd also like to do is display a list of the child terms for each parent category on a `taxonomy-mytax-myterm.php` template for each parent. I'm trying to manipulate the code below to do this (while excluding the parent still) but I'm not sure how / where to specify the current parent and to grab all the terms under the parent.

Also, curious if it would be possible to achieve pagination using this method on a taxonomy archive like this? I have found ways of achieving pagination via page-template, but learned it would not work on archive-template for CPT. Not sure if this applies to taxonomy archive templates as well?

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  );
$terms = get_terms( 'mytaxname', $args );
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        if( 0 == $term->parent )
            continue;

        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $term->term_id ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a><br/>';
    } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are on a taxonomy page, you can get the parent from the term being displayed by using  the following code with [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object). See [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) for the objects that are returned

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object('term');
  $term = $queried_object->parent;
```

To get the taxonomy, you can simply just add

```
$tax = $queried_object->taxonomy;
```

below the code above. This can then be used in the code above as follows

```
<?php

$queried_object = get_queried_object('term');
  $term_parent = $queried_object->parent;
  $tax = $queried_object->taxonomy;

$args = array(
  'parent' => $term_parent,
  'orderby' => 'name',
  );

$terms = get_terms( $tax, $args );
 if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a><br/>';
    } 
}
?>
```

The code above can be used either above or below the loop in your `taxonomy-mytax-myterm.php` to display a list of terms from the term's parent.

As for your second question, the answer is no. Archive pages are not meant to create a paginated index list of objects. They are exclusively meant to display post in that specific hierarchy, so a taxonomy archive is meant to display a paginated "list", if you will, of posts from a specific term, not a paginated index list of terms.

To understand what is classified as archives to need to dig into core. Take a look at [wp-includes/query.php#L1615](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.2/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1615)

```
1615     if ( $this->is_post_type_archive || $this->is_date || $this->is_author || $this->is_category || $this->is_tag || $this->is_tax )
1616     $this->is_archive = true;
```

So from that, the following is regarded as archive pages

- category.php
- tag.php
- archive.php
- author.php
- taxonomy.php
- date.php

So, if you need to have a paginated index page of terms, you are going to need to stick to a page template for that purpose

For additional info, go and check the following links

- [Some doubts about how the main query and the custom query works in this custom theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/155956/31545)
- [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Comment: Thank you very much Pieter, that was very beneficial to me! Most gracious for your time on this.

Comment: It is my pleasure. Glad you found this useful. Enjoy :-)