# How to create tag.php

Tags: templates, tags

How do I create a tag.php template that will work for every post that contain tags?

I created few Tags like = Food, Drink and Fruit

> post 1 have Food and Drink tags
>
> post 2 have Food and Fruit tags

How do I create a single page for those post of the tags?

My code looks like this, but it didn't show anything.

```
function get_tags_post($tag_name){
    $original_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $brand_name= $tag_name;
    $args=array(
        'posts_per_page'=>5, 
        'tag' => $brand_name
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        single_tag_title();
        echo '</li>';
    endwhile; endif;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $original_query;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Please, if anyone knows which part of the code is wrong, tell me.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately all of your code is wrong. What you are doing is the same as [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), which should never be used. Also, never swap the main query on any type of archive page or on the home page for a custom query

To create a tag page, just simply make a copy of your index.php, and rename it tag.php. Here is a copy of the bundled theme, twentyfourteen's tag.php just to give you an idea.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Tag pages
 *
 * Used to display archive-type pages for posts in a tag.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="archive-header">
                <h1 class="archive-title"><?php printf( __( 'Tag Archives: %s', 'pietergoosen' ), single_tag_title( '', false ) ); ?></h1>

                <?php
                    // Show an optional term description.
                    $term_description = term_description();
                    if ( ! empty( $term_description ) ) :
                        printf( '<div class="taxonomy-description">%s</div>', $term_description );
                    endif;
                ?>
            </header><!-- .archive-header -->

            <?php
                $counter = 1; //Starts counter for post column lay out

                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        ?>
                <div class="entry-column<?php echo ( $counter%2  ? ' left' : ' right' ); ?>">

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                </div>  

        <?php   

            $counter++; //Update the counter

            endwhile;

        pietergoosen_pagination();

        else :
                    // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

                endif;
            ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar( 'content' );
get_footer();
```

Go and check out the following links as well

- [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)
- [Some doubts about how the main query and the custom query works in this custom theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

**EDIT**

Just to comment on your code, you should properly indent your code. As your code stands, it makes it hard to read. It is also difficult to debug.

Go and read [coding-standards/php/#indentation](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#indentation) for more information

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use your specific wp_query (which btw. is absolutely not wrong and can be used if you know what you're doing and use safety measures - like try not to use $_GET so often and if u do try to strip_tags() it or use (int) before it if you want to pass only a number).

You can query for archive with tags in index.php (If you want to have only 1 universal template for standard wp posts) or by creating tags.php in main template folder root (where the template index.php and other template files are) which is exactly the same as index.php but fires when you looking for pages like: [www.webage.com/tag/some-tag-name](http://www.webage.com/tag/some-tag-name)

First, use get_queried_object(); to get the actual object. It's good to apply it to a variable to save some transfer:

```
$qObject = get_queried_object();
```

If you work on the index.php it's good practice to create a variable to distinguish if its tags archive or not so you can use it later:

```
$isArchiveTag = (($qObject->taxonomy == 'post_tag')?true:false);
```

Don't have to create it if you working on tag.php.

Now, if you're using wp_query it should look like this:

```
$postArgs = array(      
    'post_type'    => 'post',
    'showposts'    => -1,
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'parent' => 0,
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'orderby'   => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tag' => (($isArchiveTag)?$qObject->slug:'')            
);
    
$query = new WP_Query($postArgs);
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $currentPost = get_post(); // if you want to declare variable to hold post data
            //enter your code code here
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

To get active tag title you can use

```
single_tag_title( '', false );
```

or

```
$qObject->name;
```

To get all the tags as wp_object and apply it to variable use

```
$tags = get_terms('post_tag');
```

Have fun :)

Comment: I guess that's an answer to the more general "how to create tag.php" than the specific question here?