# Posts navigation in custom post type single.php not working

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I have a custom post type called "internpage", here are the args:

```
$args = array(     
'label'                 => __( 'Interne Seite', 'text_domain' ),
'description'           => __( 'Seiten interner Bereich', 'text_domain' ),
'labels'                => $labels,
'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'page-attributes', 'revisions' ),
'hierarchical'          => true,
'public'                => true,
'show_ui'               => true,
'show_in_menu'          => true,
'menu_position'         => 70,
'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-lock',
'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
'can_export'            => true,
'has_archive'           => false,
'exclude_from_search'   => false,
'publicly_queryable'    => true,
'capability_type'       => 'page',
);
```

The template is called "single-internpage.php". On one of these pages I have a custom loop who shows posts of another custom post type ("internpost"):

```
$args=array(
    'post_type'      => 'internpost',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'paged'          => $paged
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;
endif;
posts_nav_link();
```

With this I display the latest 3 posts of this custom post type ... inside the single-internpage.php.

This works but I can't get the pagination running. When I hover the posts_nav_link like "next page" firefox shows me that the adress is".../page/2" which is cool. But when I click on this nothing happens, the page reloads and the URL stays the same (without ".../page/2").

When I put the same loop in a normal pages template of e. g. the contact page, it works.

Answer (score 1):

This question seams to be the same as this one

[posts_nav_link on single post template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158926/posts-nav-link-on-single-post-template)

hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I think I have to use a page template or an archive page instead.