# latest posts-widget displays all posts on archive page but works great anywhere else

Tags: widgets, page-template, custom-post-type-archives

I noticed the latest posts widget in my footer displaying all posts. Anywhere else on my page, it displays only the amount of posts it should.
I am using a custom theme and this is my archive.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="maincol">

    <article id="page-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="page">
        <header class="page-header">
            <h1 class="page-title">Post Type Archive Title</h1>
        </header>

        <?php $posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_key=premium&posts_per_page=6'); ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <h3 class="toggle">Filter</h3>
            <div id="filterbox">
                 <?php echo do_shortcode('[ULWPQSF id=82 formtitle="0"]'); ?>
                 <small class="toggle-close">close</small>
            </div>

            <?php
                echo '<div class="objects">';
                echo '<ul class="list-objects clear">';
                while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();
                    get_template_part('content', 'my-post-type');
                }
                if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) :
                    wp_pagenavi();
                endif;
        endif; 
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
        wp_reset_query();
        wp_reset_postdata();

        ?>

    </article>
 </div><!-- maincol-->

<aside class="sidebar" id="sidebar-main">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</aside>
<div class="clear"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Can you possibly spot the mistake?

Comment: The code you posted is a template file, not the widget code. Can you post the widget code? Anyway I can give a good advise: change the `query_posts` function for a `new WP_Query` instance. DO NOT USE `query_post` in a theme or plugin file. NEVER.

Comment: what is the shortcode `ULWPQSF` doing?

Comment: you should never change the main query on any type of archive page. You should use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main main query before it is executed instead. `query_posts` is a culprit to many problems, never use it at all. Take you time and read [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) I've recently done

Comment: ULWPQSF is a plugin shortcode for Ultimate WP Query Search Filter, it creates checkboxes for my categories to filter by. @cybmeta & Pieter Goosen: thank you, I didn't know using query_posts was that problematic, I used a pre_get_posts function, I'll post that solution later as an answer if you don't mind

Comment: That is why I always hammer on the point I've made. There are always beter more reliable methods to use than `query_posts`. I'm glad you solved your problem, and that I could be of help. BTW, +1 for just taking the time and posting the solution to your own question. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from @Pieter Goosen and @cybmeta I changed my way to order the posts on the archive page by making use of `pre_get_posts`

What I wanted my archive page to do is displaying posts with custom field value 1 and named "premium" (my method to create custom sticky posts) first and then all the "normal" posts.

I added the following lines to my functions.php file (Edit: added !is_admin() as suggested in Pieter's comment):

```
function custom_archive_query($query) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive('my-custom-post-type') &&  $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 8 );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'premium');
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_archive_query');
```

It's somewhat important to use `$query->is_main_query()` in the `if`-statement, because otherwise every other kind of query (e.g. WP menus or latest posts-widgets) won't display anything.

Comment: It is very important to use `is_main_query` for the simple fact that `pre_get_posts` alters all queries, back end and front end, so you should direct it only at the main query. It is important to use `!is_admin` check as well to inhibit back end changes :-)