# Display one post on category.php: Wrong featured image

Tags: categories, loop, images

**What I want**

When a user opens a category link, there should be automatically displayed the first queried post.

My query looks like this:

```
    <?php global $query_string;
            $posts = query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=1&order=ASC'); ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**The problem**

The category URL displays the first queried content, but the wrong featured image, which is taken from the last queried post, meaning `order=DESC` is used.

Any idea how to solve this?

**Maybe important**

The featured images are set as full screen background images via backstretch.js by using

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'backstretch', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'backstretch-set', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/js/backstretch-set.js' , array( 'jquery', 'backstretch' ), '1.0.0' );

wp_localize_script( 'backstretch-set', 'BackStretchImg', array( 'src' => wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) ) );
```

Comment: Try using `WP_Query` to get the posts, `query_posts` shouldn't be used, never. Also, I don't think you can call `get_post_thumbnail_id`, and at the point it's called there's no ID, so the `get_the_ID()` method should be failing, try turning debugging on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `query_posts`, and also do not replace the main query with a custom query. This causes more issues than solving the one issue you had before with the main query. I've done a complete post on these issues recently that you can check out [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

According to your query, the only two things you need to change is `posts_per_page` and `order` to do this, you can simply use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the query variables before the main query is executed. You can specifically target only category pages with the [conditional tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

To solve this issue, return to the default loop on your category page. You'll just need the following on category.php, nothing more.

```
<?php 
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post(); 
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
    }
}
?>
```

In your functions.php, use this code with `pre_get_posts` to alter the amount of posts per page and how they are ordered on category pages

```
function wpse_change_category( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '1' );
        $query->set( 'order','ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_change_category' );
```

Comment: awesome! thanks for the hint with pre_get_posts. I am going to read about that. Thanks!