# Adding custom post type to loop

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

Hope someone can help me with this. I have a custom post type ('article') in my WordPress installation, and I'd like to display those posts alongside the default posts in the regular post feed.

This is my current loop:

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        global $more;
        $more = 0;

    //include the post template
    locate_template( array( 'includes/post-template.php' ), true, false );
}

locate_template( array( 'includes/post-pagination.php' ), true, false );

}else {
_e( 'No posts available', 'pexeto' );
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked out `pre_get_posts`

Comment: How would I go about integrating that? (Apologies, I'm pretty new to PHP/WP development)

Comment: @TomasCot answer should do the trick. For extra reading, check out [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

Answer (score 11):

You need something like this in you functions.php file, I'm using the action Pieter suggested.

```
function add_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'article') );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query' );
```

You can [read more about the `pre_get_posts` in the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

Comment: Make sure to add a `!is_admin()` check to your `if` statement so that doesn't gunk up any admin screens!

Comment: @mrwweb, With the `is_home()` is enough.

Comment: Good point. I think you're right. I generally like checking for `is_main_query()` and `is_admin()` right off the bat (as in [this example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Changing_the_number_of_posts_per_page.2C_by_post_type)) but that's moot here.

Comment: @mrwweb, when in doubt, always check. In this particular case isn't neccesary

Comment: Good snippet. It should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: I used `!is_admin()` because it will prevent the CTP to load in admin, but will load in home and archive pages, which is my objective.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this and it worked like a charm.

```
function add_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
  if ( is_home() ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', '2nd-post-type', '3rd-post-type') );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query' );
```

You can see it in action at http://bestmotorcycleroads.com