# Order by meta value, pro first, then free

Tags: query-posts

```
query_posts($query_string . '&meta_value=pro&orderby=rand');
```

I get pro list with random, but I want `pro` as well as free, but with `pro` list first, then `meta_value` `free` list.

I also set `orderby` `meta_value`

```
    query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=meta_value_num');
```

This does not work, and in query string default for `cat`. It will take `orderby` `date` with both `meta value = pro` and `free`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. To start you off, please feel free to visit our [tour] page to get a feel on how the site operate. Also visit [help] for any site related questions. To come back to your question, I just need to clear some issues, you want to randomly fetch posts from a meta key with free and pro as meta values. Say you get 10 posts, 4 pro and 6 free, the 4 pro posts must be shown first, then the other 6 free. Just a tip, do not use `query_posts`, rather use `WP_Query`

Comment: k thanks means i used query_post in - inbuild function of theme. tax-list.php so i need to create new cat.php file ? for new loop ? or used wp in same file ?

Comment: Use the same file, just change `query_posts` to `WP_Query`. Also, please advice on my last comment whether this is what you are trying to do

Comment: ya i am trying like. 
in page of category listing  
post type = listing 
meta value = pro and free  but first display pro then free .so order by meta value order DESC 

 WP_Query($query_string . '&orderby=meta_value_num');

Call to undefined function WP_Query() 

error

Comment: for ex in my category page if there 10 post then i want 10 with random but meta value = pro first then meta_value = free then. ok . 
right now random working .with all or only post or only free. but i want order by meta value so easy for me to solve this issues

Comment: Please visit [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to understand how the meta query parameters work and how it should be constructed. Also, check the orderby parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I fire away, just one note, **NEVER** (my emphasis) make use of [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to create custom queries

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

Rather make use of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to create custom queries, but **ONLY** if you can't modify the main query with [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). For more info, check out [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

Assuming that there are only two values for your `meta_key` (*PLEASE NOTE: For testing purposes, I have used my own meta key, you should replace this with your own*), namely `pro` and `free`, you can just retrieve posts that has this specific `meta_key`. Your query will then look something like this:

```
$args = [
    'meta_key'          => 'packages',
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page'    => 5,
];

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If you however have more values than just these two, then you will need to adjust your query to include the `meta_value` and then make use of the `meta_compare` parameter. Your adjusted query will then become:

```
$args = [
    'meta_key'          => 'packages',
    'meta_value'        => 'free, pro',
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'meta_compare'      => 'IN',
    'posts_per_page'    => 5,
];
```

(*PS! Before I go on, you should note that the `orderby` parameter has changed in version 4.0, but this will not work in this instance.*

Great, you will now have 5 posts that was retrieved randomly which has either a `meta_value` of `pro` or `free`

Now we need to sort them. The best possible solution is to make use of [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the returned array of posts in `$the_query->posts` according to the value of the posts `meta_value`. You will then need to unset `$the_query->posts` and then reset it with the reordered post array.

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php
$args = [
    'meta_key'          => 'packages',
    'meta_value'        => 'free, pro',
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'meta_compare'      => 'IN',
    'posts_per_page'    => 5,
];

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$post_metas = $the_query->posts;

usort( $post_metas, function( $a, $b ){
    $a = get_post_meta( $a->ID , 'packages', true ) ;
    $b = get_post_meta( $b->ID, 'packages', true ) ;

    if ( $a == $b ) {
        return 0;
    }
        return ( $a > $b ) ? -1 : 1;
    }
);

unset($the_query->posts);
$the_query->posts = $post_metas;

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        echo '<li>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'packages', true ). '</br>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
} 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

You will just need to adjust the query variables to suit your needs and also adjust the loop to display what is needed

This is not the only way to achieve it though, you can also move your sorting function to your functions.php and specifically target this custom query

Comment: ye i got pro first as well as random thanks . but now its display result as all post.. but i want only for perticuler category. like i click on categoryand i want post of only that category thanks 
also my post type = listing

Comment: Just add `'cat' => get_queried_object('cat')->cat_ID,` to your arguments

Comment: thanks i got perfect output in database. when i pass output sql. now i just need to change in html means echo part. asl but right now its pro after free but i want that value as random .?.thanks 
i also need to changes in html or what i want to display in page thanks

Comment: Glad that is solved. As for the HTML section, that is out of scope of this question. HTML related stuff is also off topic on this site. If you need help with the html structure of your page, you should ask a new question over at stackoverflow.com which is better suited for these type of questions. Thank you

Comment: thanks a lot u saved my day. i got right data now just need in echo. an image title and des. with as per theme formate. ok thanks sir :)

Comment: it will not take post per page.. this will break pagination in ...!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to query by the `meta_key` instead of `meta_value`:

```
 $query_string . '&meta_key=name_of_key_that_stores_free_or_pro&orderby=meta_value_num'
```

Comment: thanks for reply but its not working i used 

query_posts($query_string . '&meta_key=J_listing_type&orderby=meta_value_num');

but not working

Comment: Try just `orderby=meta_value`

Comment: i try this also but not working :(