# Order by meta value pro first then meta value free in my search function

Tags: query, post-meta, meta-query, meta-value

My meta key is `geo_listing_type` and this key have 2 `meta_value`, `pro` and `free`. 
I want to order these by `pro` first then `free`

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!--Start Content Wrapper-->
<div class="content_wrapper">
    <div class="grid_16 alpha">
        <div class="featured_content">
            <h1>
                <?php
                $sfrom = $_REQUEST['sfrom'];
                $location = $_REQUEST['location'];
                if ($sfrom !== "" && $location == "") {
                    printf(__(U_SRC_FR . ' %s', THEME_SLUG), '' . $sfrom . '');
                } elseif ($sfrom == "" && $location !== "") {
                    printf(__(NEAR . ' %s', THEME_SLUG), $location);
                } elseif ($sfrom !== "" && $location !== "") {
                    printf(__(U_SRC_FR . ' %s ' . NEAR . ' %s', THEME_SLUG), '' . $sfrom . '', $location);
                }
                ?>
            </h1>     
            <?php
            $results = gc_multi_search($sfrom, $location);
            if (isset($_GET['pn'])) { // Get pn from URL vars if it is present
                $pn = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['pn']); // filter everything but numbers for security(new)
            } else { // If the pn URL variable is not present force it to be value of page number 1
                $pn = 1;
            }

            $itemsPerPage = get_option('posts_per_page');

            $lastPage = ceil($results['query'] / $itemsPerPage);

            if ($pn < 1) { // If it is less than 1
                $pn = 1; // force if to be 1
            } else if ($pn > $lastPage) { // if it is greater than $lastpage
                $pn = $lastPage; // force it to be $lastpage's value
            }

            $centerPages = "";
            $sub1 = $pn - 1;
            $sub2 = $pn - 2;
            $add1 = $pn + 1;
            $add2 = $pn + 2;
            if ($pn == 1) {
                $centerPages .= '<li><a class="current" href="">' . $pn . '</a></li>';
                $centerPages .= '<li> <a href="' . site_url(GC_SEARCH . "/?pn=$add1&sfrom=$sfrom&location=$location") . '">' . $add1 . '</a></li>';
            } else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
                $centerPages .= '<li> <a href="' . site_url(GC_SEARCH . "/?pn=$sub1&sfrom=$sfrom&location=$location") . '">' . $sub1 . '</a></li>';
                $centerPages .= '<li><a class="current" href="">' . $pn . '</a></li>';
            } else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
                $centerPages .= '<li><a href="' . site_url(GC_SEARCH . "/?pn=$sub2&sfrom=$sfrom&location=$location") . '">' . $sub2 . '</a></li>';
                $centerPages .= '<li><a href="' . site_url(GC_SEARCH . "/?pn=$sub1&sfrom=$sfrom&location=$location") . '">' . $sub1 . '</a></li>';
                $centerPages .= '<li><a class="current" href="">' . $pn . '</a></li>';
                $centerPages .= '<li><a href="' . site_url(GC_SEARCH . "/?pn=$add2&sfrom=$sfrom&location=$location") . '">' . $add1 . '</a></li>';
                $centerPages .= '<li><a href="' . site_url(GC_SEARCH . "/?pn=$add2&sfrom=$sfrom&location=$location") . '">' . $add2 . '</a></li>';
            } else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
                $centerPages .= '<li> <a href="' . site_url(GC_SEARCH . "/?pn=$sub1&sfrom=$sfrom&location=$location") . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> </li>';
                $centerPages .= '<li><a class="current" href="">' . $pn . '</a></li>';
                $centerPages .= '<li><a href="' . site_url(GC_SEARCH . "/?pn=$add1&sfrom=$sfrom&location=$location") . '">' . $add1 . '</a></li>';
            }

            $limit = 'LIMIT ' . ($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage . ',' . $itemsPerPage;
            $paginationDisplay = "<ul class='paginate'>"; // Initialize the pagination output variable
            if ($lastPage != "1") {
                //$paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $pn . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage . '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';

                if ($pn != 1) {
                    $previous = $pn - 1;
                    $paginationDisplay .= '<li><a href="' . site_url(GC_SEARCH . "/?pn=$previous&sfrom=$sfrom&location=$location") . '">&laquo;</a></li>';
                }
                $paginationDisplay .= $centerPages;
                if ($pn != $lastPage) {
                    $nextPage = $pn + 1;
                    $paginationDisplay .= '<li><a href="' . site_url(GC_SEARCH . "/?pn=$nextPage&sfrom=$sfrom&location=$location") . '">&raquo;</a></li> ';
                }                
            }
            $paginationDisplay .= '</ul>';
            if($pn < 1){
                $paginationDisplay = '';
            }


            $results = gc_multi_search($sfrom, $location, $limit);
            if ($results['result']) {
                foreach ($results['result'] as $q) {
                    $featured_class = '';
                    $is_pro = get_post_meta($q->ID, 'geocraft_listing_type', true);
                    if ($is_pro == 'pro') {
                        $featured_class = 'featured';
                    }
                    $img_meta = get_post_meta($q->ID, 'geocraft_meta_image1', true);
                    ?>
                    <!--Start Featured Post-->
                    <div class="featured_post">
                        <div class="<?php echo $featured_class; ?>">
                            <!--Start Featured thumb-->
                            <div class="featured_thumb">
                                <?php if ((function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())) { ?>
                                    <?php inkthemes_get_thumbnail(128, 108, '', $img_meta); ?>                    
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <?php search_get_image(128, 108, '', $img_meta, get_permalink($q->ID)); ?> 
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                                <?php if ($is_pro == 'pro') { ?>
                                    <img class="ribbon" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ribbon.png"/>                   
                                <?php } ?>
                                <ul class="star_rating">
                                    <?php
                                    echo geocraft_get_post_rating_star($q->ID);
                                    ?>
                                </ul>
                                <span class="review_desc"><?php  gc_comments_popup_link($q->ID,N_RV, _RV, '% ' . REVIEW); ?></span> </div>
                            <!--End Featured thumb-->
                            <div class="f_post_content">
                                <h4 style="margin-bottom: 3px !important;" class="f_post_title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($q->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" ><?php echo get_the_title($q->ID); ?></a></h4>
                                <?php if (get_post_meta($q->ID, 'geo_address', true)): ?>
                                    <p class="f_post_meta"><img src="<?php echo TEMPLATEURL . '/images/location-icon.png'; ?>"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo get_post_meta($q->ID, 'geo_address', true); ?></p>                               
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php
                                $excerpt = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $q->post_content);
                                $excerpt = substr(strip_tags($excerpt), 0, 111);
                                printf("%s", $excerpt);
                                if (strlen($excerpt) > 110)
                                    echo '&nbsp;<a href="' . get_permalink($q->ID) . '">' . '[...] Read More' . '</a>';
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--End Featured Post-->
                    <?php
                }
            }else {
                ?>            
                <div class = "featured_post">
                    <p class = "place"><?php echo NO_LST_FND; ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <div class="paging"><span style="float:right;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_8 omega">
        <?php
        global $post;
        get_sidebar(POST_TYPE);
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End Content Wrapper-->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Above is my search function.

- My post type is = `listing`
- `meta key = geocraft_listing_type`
- `meta_value` are `pro` and `free`

I want this above search function as `pro` value first then `free` with random.

Currently, per function, posts are sorted by id. If I add after group by ASC and DESC then it will work, but i want `pro` value first then `free`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2 - FINAL EDIT**

Just before I start with this edit, just a few things here

- The code in my answer are the basics and meant to demonstrate the concepts. I have now tested both sets of code, and all works as expected. You have to add all your desired mark-up, styling and template tags yourself.
- On the part of implementation, this is entirely up to you, we are not here to implement code for you. It is expected that you do at least have some knowledge on how to use and implement this code into your theme

You have confirmed that this is your search.php, which renders my code in my original answer useless. You should never change the main query with a custom one as this is always problematic as you have seen. Please see [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) I have done on this subject

My solution for you would be is to paste the code from my first edit (**EDIT 1**) in your functions.php. You will have to modify the `pre_get_posts` action as needed. I have tested the code and it works perfectly. For this to work, you need to make use of the **main loop** in search.php.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

What I've read and understood from your question is that all `pro` values must be first ordered by date, and then `free` to follow ordered randomly

We are going to make use of basically the same idea as in [your previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165253/31545) with a few modifications

Just one note before I start, you should not make use of custom SQL queries. Make use of [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) rather to create/adjust/modify your queries accordingly

I'm still a SQL learner, so I'm going to scrap your idea and work with `WP_Query`

The type of sorting that you want is not possible with the above mentioned native functions. Also, you don't need to run two queries to achieve this, one is enough.

My idea here would be to retrieve all posts within the `meta_value` of `pro` and `free`. We will keep the default 'orderby' and 'order' parameters as this does not matter. We will use PHP to achieve the desired sort orders

So, lets code:

**STEP 1**

As previously stated, we need get all the posts which have a `meta_value` of `pro` and `value`

```
$args = [
    'post_type'         => 'listing',
    'meta_key'          => 'geocraft_listing_type',
    'meta_value'        => 'free, pro',
    'meta_compare'      => 'IN',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
];

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**STEP 2**

In my personal opinion, the best way to achieve your sort order is to break the `$posts` array into two separate arrays, one array will hold all posts with a `meta_value` of `pro` while the other array will hold posts with `meta_value` `free`.

```
$free = [];
$pro = [];
foreach ( $the_query->posts as $post ) {
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'geocraft_listing_type', true );
    if ( 'free' == $meta ) {
        $free[] = $post;  
    }else{
        $pro[] = $post;  
    }
}
unset($post);
```

**STEP 3**

The array which holds the posts with `meta_value` `pro` will be left untouched, this array of posts will already be sorted according to post date. We need to sort the array which holds the posts with `meta_value` `free`

As you need this posts to be sorted randomly, we are going to make use of the PHP function [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to shuffle these posts so that they are going to be displayed randomly

```
shuffle($free);
```

**STEP 4**

We need to unset the original `$posts` and reset it with a new value. This value will be created by merging our two arrays together, `pro` first, then `free`. To achieve this, make use of [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). This new array will be set as the new value of `$posts`

```
unset($the_query->posts);
$the_query->posts = array_merge($pro, $free);
```

**STEP 5**

You can now loop through your posts as normal

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        echo '<li>' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'geocraft_listing_type', true ). '</br>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
} 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**ALL TOGETHER NOW**

```
<?php
$args = [
    'post_type'         => 'listing',
    'meta_key'          => 'geocraft_listing_type',
    'meta_value'        => 'free, pro',
    'meta_compare'      => 'IN',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
];

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$free = [];
$pro = [];
foreach ( $the_query->posts as $post ) {
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'geocraft_listing_type', true );
    if ( 'free' == $meta ) {
        $free[] = $post;  
    }else{
        $pro[] = $post;  
    }
}
unset($post);
shuffle($free);
unset($the_query->posts);
$the_query->posts = array_merge($pro, $free);

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        echo '<li>' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'geocraft_listing_type', true ). '</br>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
} 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

You can modify this code to use `pre_get_posts` and `the_posts` filter if this is suppose to be the main query.

**EDIT 1**

If this was suppose to be done on the search page as the main query, you would use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query on the search page. I'm not going to explain everything in detail as it should work in the same way as above with `WP_Query`

In your functions.php, add the following code. This will change the main query only for the search page

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'listings' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'geocraft_listing_type' );
        $query->set( 'meta_value', 'free, pro' );
        $query->set( 'meta_compare', 'IN' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    }
});
```

You are now going to use `the_posts` filter to filter the sorting order on the search page.

So, again in your functions.php, add the following code

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', function ($posts, $query) {
  if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
    $free = [];
    $pro = [];
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'geocraft_listing_type', true );
        if ( 'free' == $meta ) {
            $free[] = $post;  
        }else{
            $pro[] = $post;  
        }
    }
    unset($post);
    shuffle($free);
    $posts = array_merge($pro, $free);
    }
    return $posts;  
}, 
10, 2 );
```

Inside your search.php you don't need to modify anything. All you need in there is the default loop.

Comment: thanks you sir but this time my template search.php is diff.so i cant solve. thanks for suggetion i will send you full search.php file plz help me on that. thanks again.

Comment: You have to modify and implement the code to suite your needs. The code above is very basic and written to explain the basics.

Comment: thank you sir. but i try too much time. but i cant fig out. so plz help me on this. plz thanks again.

Comment: Just one question, where did you used the code in your question, my code above the edit should simply just replace the code in your question

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: thanks for reply. i used your code in search.php and also add that function.php code. but now. all list come with pro first and then free. i want. only search list.! thanks..

Comment: You should **only** use code in **EDIT 1**. And this line `if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {` only targets the search page. You most probably deleted those lines. As I said, my code **works**. I have testes, and retested it.

Comment: i just echo my theme seach query and result is 

 SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (wp_posts.ID = '10') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC

Comment: Please reread my answer please. As I stated, you are going to use the default sorting order in wordpress. That is why you see that SQL output. The posts are sorted by PHP, **not wordpress**. You **cannot** sort by two meta keys in wordpress natively. I don't want to be rude, but if you can't implement my code or don't know how or even don't understand it, please hire a developer to help you with that. I've made everything very clear in my answer and explained as well as I could. Thank you

Comment: Please, **don't use step 1-5 in search.php, only main loop, only use edit 1 in functions.php, nothing else** I don't know how to make this clearer anymore. Hire someone to assist you futher

Comment: ya i try that also. i only add that 2 function but nothing to change in search result :(. same result.!!