# Custom Post Type Archive Not Showing Posts

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to create a custom post type "Press" with an archive. I think I've done everything needed, yet when I go to /press url, no posts are showing up. I entered "test" in my archive-press.php, but that's not showing up either, so I assume the archive php file is not connected to the press page.

In my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
    function create_post_type(){
    register_post_type( 'press',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
         'name' => __('Press'),
         'singular_name' => __('Press Item'),
         'add_new' => __('Add New'),
         'add_new_item' => __('Add New Item'),
         'edit_item' => __('Edit Item'),
         'new_item' => __('New Item'),
         'all_items' => __('All Items'),
         'view_item' => __('View Items'),
         'search_items' => __('Search Press'),
         'not_found' =>  __('No Items found'),
         'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Items Found in Trash'), 
         'parent_item_colon' => '',
         'menu_name' => 'Press'
        ),
    'labels' => $press_labels,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => 10,
    'query_var' => true,
    'has_archive' =>true,
    'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','excerpt')
    )
    ); 
    }
```

My archive-press.php:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query -> query('post_type=press&showposts=20');
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="press-item">
    <div class="press-img"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium');?></div>
    <div class="press-content">
    <div class="press-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?> </div>
    <div class="press-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;  ?>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

My Permalink is set to url/%category%/%postname%/

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You may have to flush your permalinks. Go to Settings/Permalinks and click save to flush them. If that does not work there is something else hanging it up. Something I found wrong in you code is that you have `'labels' => $press_labels,` the array you have defined before that is correct. Not sure but that could also be tripping things up?

Comment: Flush your permalinks and then check [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545). Never drop the main query for a custom one

Answer (score 1):

I generally include this chunk of code with my custom post types:

```
// Load the custom post type archive page template
add_filter( 'archive_template', 'posttype_archive_template' ) ;
function posttype_archive_template( $archive_template ) {
  global $post;
  if ( is_post_type_archive ( 'posttype' ) ) {
    if(file_exists(PLUGIN_PATH. '/archive-posttype.php'))
       $archive_template = PLUGIN_PATH. '/archive-posttype.php';
  }
  return $archive_template;
}
```

Comment: And change "posttype" to the name of the post type, in this case "press"?