# problem in taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php pagination

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pagination, taxonomy

my custom taxonomy is:

```
$image_labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'تصویر', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'تصویر', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'تصویر', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'تصویرها', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'تصویر', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'تصویر', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'تصویر جدید', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'اضافه کردن تصویر جدید', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'ویرایش تصویر', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'به‌روزرسانی تصویر', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( '', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'جستجو در تصویرها', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'اضافه / حذف', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'انتخاب از میان بیشتر استفاده شده‌ها', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'فیلم مورد نظر یافت نشد', 'text_domain' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                       => 'image',
    'with_front'                 => true,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $image_labels,
    #'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'query_var'                  => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    #'query_var'                  => true,
    'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
);
register_taxonomy( 'multimedia_image', array( 'multimedia' ), $args );
```

my pagination is:

function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {

```
if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
    }

global $paged;
    if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
    }
if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
if(!$numpages) {
    $numpages = 1;
    }   
}
$pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format'          => 'page/%#%',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => false,
    'prev_text'       => __('« صفحه قبل'),
    'next_text'       => __('صفحه بعد »'),
    'type'            => 'list',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
);
$paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

if ($paginate_links) {
    echo "<div class='navigation'>";
        echo "<ol class='wp-paginate'>";
            echo $paginate_links;
        echo "</ol>";
    echo "</div>";
  }}
```

and my taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section class="clearfix">
    <div id="right-col" class="right">
        <section class="archive">

        <?php $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
                        $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
                            $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, 'multimedia_image' );
                                $term_id = $current_term->term_id; ?>
        <?php $term = $wp_query->queried_object; ?>
        <?php $term_name = get_queried_object()->term_id; ?>
        <?php echo '<h1>'.$term->name.'</h1>'; ?>
        <?php $image_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_status' =>'publish',
            'post_type' =>'multimedia',
            'tax_query' => array(
                                 array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'multimedia_image',
                                        'field'    => 'id',
                                        'terms'    => $term_name,
                                      ) 
                                ),
            'order' =>'asc',
            'orderby' =>'ID',
            'posts_per_page' =>'10',
            'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1       
        )); ?>
        <?php if($image_query->have_posts()) : while($image_query->have_posts()) : $image_query->the_post(); ?>                
            <article class="post clearfix">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('مستطیلی', array('class' => 'shadow right')); ?></a>
                <div class="left shadow">
                    <small class="rootitr"><?php #if(function_exists('the_field')) the_field('rootitr'); ?></small>
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                </div>
            </article>
```

```
            <?php if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {custom_pagination($image_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged); } ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php get_template_part('not-found'); ?>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </section>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar('single'); ?>
</section>
```

my problem:
when i click in page=2, return: 404 error and page not found
help me please

Comment: Why not a default `while(have_post()):the_post(); ...; endwhile; global $wp_query; $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; if ( $total_pages > 1 ) {
 next_posts_link('Older posts');
 previous_posts_link('Newer posts');
}`? Is that working?

Comment: tanx. but, Where should I use? in single.php?

Comment: Why the `single.php` comes here? We are talking about `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`, aren't we? If that code works, then everything's ok. Need to workout on your code then. If not, then something fishy somewhere.

Comment: not work your code...

Comment: i'm test many plugin and code for pagination. but dosent work any thing. i think The problem is elsewhere, but i cant find it...

Comment: Please paste the code for taxonomy-{$taxonomy}.php in an [edit] to your question, not in comments

Comment: pasted it in: http://notepad.cc/wopelu39

Comment: As I thought. Don't use custom queries in place of the main query in arhive pages. See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

Comment: so, What should I do?

Comment: Delete the custom query and replace the default loop.

Comment: if i use defult loop in taxonomy-image.php, but no display any post...