# Use specific category for every author on author page

Tags: categories

The authorpage is begin generated, and every post that an author has made will be shown.
However I only want to show posts from a specific category (id=1).

So basically, when you visit

> mysite.com/author/John

you should see only posts from John, with category ID=1 and on

> mysite.com/author/Bob

you should see only posts from Bob, with category ID=1.

When I do this in archive.php:

```
/* Start the Loop */ 
query_posts('cat=1');                               
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    get_template_part('content', get_post_format());
}
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, every post in category 1, will be shown on every author page...(You see Bobs and Johns posts on Johns author-page).

I have also tried this, but same results as above:

```
$curauth = get_userdata($row->ID);
$user_link = get_author_posts_url($curauth->ID);
$posts = get_posts(array(
     'author' => $curauth->ID,
     'cat' => 1
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
    )
);
$post_count = count($posts);
```

I have 2 questions.

1. Should I code in archive.php or should I make the adjustments in author.php (not available in the theme).
2. More importantly, how do I show `catID=1` for every author ?

PS: View full code [here](http://pastebin.com/NkZP4UJ9)

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Just one tip, properly format your code before posting, it makes it easier for others to read and help you :-) Feel free to take a [tour] and also read through [ask]. Also, we have a one question per post policy :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a quite extensive post on a similar subject that you can read [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545). Also take your time and read all linked posts.

In there I have explained why you should not be using `query_posts` and why you should not use custom queries in place of the main query

A few things here:

- Remember to create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), do not make changes to a theme that you have not written. You will loose all your work if you update that theme
- It is real easy to create your own author archive page. Simply make a copy of your `index.php` and rename it `author.php`. It is that easy
- Use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to make changes to your author page. Do not make changes directly through a custom query on your author page. You can use the following in your functions.php

  ```
  function wpse166864_include_category( $query ) {
      if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
         $query->set( 'cat', '1' );
      }
  }
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse166864_include_category' );
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much, the code for function.php simply worked.
I'll make sure to read the links provided.
Also I have a question, just to be sure, what does "wpse166864" mean ? It's just randomly chosen for 'add_action' right ?

Comment: Great to hear it worked. On the naming convention. It is just to give the function a unique name. It simply means `[w]ord[p]ress [s]tack[e]xhange post number [166864]`