# Displaying posts on homepage - Template Page

Tags: pages, page-template, homepage

I created two template pages: `galerie.php` and `homepage.php`.

Galerie already displays posts. So Homepage is `homepage.php` and posts page is `galerie.php`.

Now the problem is that I wanted to display a post from Category `category-test` into `homepage.php`. I used the following code to try to display the posts from `category-test`:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('category_name=' . 'category-test'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
      <?php the_title(); ?>
      <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
 <?php } ?>
```

But for some reason this only displays the post title. It doesn't display the body content of the post.

What is the problem with it?

Comment: You have to use `setup_postdata( $post );` inside your `foreach` loop just before calling `the_title()`. This will make the template tags available

Comment: How? Could you please add it into my code?

Comment: Done. Just for interest sake, feel free to take a [tour] to learn how the site operates. :-)

Comment: Thank you. I come from Stack Overflow. It's pretty much the same. I know how it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template tags (like `the_content()`) aren't available when using [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). In order to make the template tags available, you have to make use of `setup_postdata( $post );`

Example:

```
<?php 
$posts = get_posts('category_name=category-test'); 
foreach($posts as $post) { 
    setup_postdata( $post );

    the_title(); ?>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked just fine. :) Btw am I doing this right? I mean, I would like to know if this is the right way of doing what I want.
And I would like to understand why did my code displayed the `the_title()` of the post but not `the_content()`

Comment: Is homepage.php a static front page. If yes, then you are you doing it correctly. Remember, you can use `get_posts` or `WP_Query` for this. I tend to prefer `WP_Query` as the template tags are available by default, and it is easier to work with if you need paginated queries.

Comment: Please see [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/155956/31545), this should answer a few questions for you

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) with any of the category parameters as its more flexible.

You can add it directly to your template or create a template tag which you can then add in any file or custom function.

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=4' );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `WP_Query`?
[Modified code, used `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts` as suggested]

```
<?php $arg = array(
    'category_name' =>  'category-test'
);
$newQ = QP_Query($arg);
while($newQ->have_posts()) : $newQ->the_post();?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Never use `query_posts`. It is just a function prone to fail unexpectitely

Comment: Never use query_posts as its highly inefficient. In this case, WP_Query is the best function.