# Problem when I try to insert pagination

Tags: pagination, navigation

All the website are building in Wordpress but I need a new section called "News", like as a blog.

I try to show 2 post and insert the pagination in my website, but when I try to view the next page, always show me my index.php and I don't know for why.

I put this code in my archive.php

```
    if (is_category('blog')){   
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged'))? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
    query_posts("posts_per_page=2&order=DESC&paged=".$paged);
    include("archives/archive-blog.php");
}else{
//show other code...
}
```

In my archive-blog.php my navigation code it's:

```
$next = get_next_posts_link('<<');
            $previous = get_previous_posts_link('>>');
            $ruta = get_bloginfo('template_url');

            echo "<div class='mi-navegacion'>";
            if ($next){
                echo "<div class='navegacion-prev'><img src='".$ruta."/imagenes/tienda-volver.png'/>".$next."</div>";
            }

            if ($previous){
                echo "<div class='navegacion-next'>".$previous."<img src='".$ruta."/imagenes/tienda-siguiente.png'/></div>";
            }                
            echo "<div class='limpia'></div>";
            echo "</div>";
```

And my url it's

```
http://localhost/myWebsite/www/category/blog/page/2/
```

But never show me the next page I only show my index.php

What can be the problem?

Edit:

Trying somethings solutions, I put this code in my category.php and archive.php

```
if (is_category('blog')){   
global $miPagina;
if(get_query_var("paged")){
    $miPagina = get_query_var("paged");
}elseif(get_query_var("page")){
    $miPagina = get_query_var("page");
}else{
    $miPagina = "1";
}

//  query_posts('category_name=blog&posts_per_page=2&order=DESC&paged='.$miPagina);

$queryBlog = array(
    "category_name"=>"blog",
    "posts_per_page"=>"2",
    "order"=>"DESC",
    "paged"=>$miPagina
);
$objetoBlog = new WP_Query($queryBlog);


if ($objetoBlog->have_posts()){
    while($objetoBlog->have_posts()){
        $objetoBlog->the_post();
        the_title();            
    }

    $siguiente = get_next_posts_link('Anterior');
    $anterior = get_previous_posts_link('Siguiente');
    $ruta = get_bloginfo('template_url');

    echo "<div class='mi-navegacion'>";
    if ($siguiente){
        echo "<div class='navegacion-prev'><img src='".$ruta."/imagenes/tienda-volver.png'/>".$siguiente."</div>";
    }

    if ($anterior){
        echo "<div class='navegacion-next'>".$anterior."<img src='".$ruta."/imagenes/tienda-siguiente.png'/></div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";

    wp_reset_postdata();
}


//query_posts('category_name=blog&posts_per_page=2&order=DESC&paged='.$miPagina);

}
```

If I use `WP_Query`, I never saw my `next_posts_link` but if I use `query_posts(...)` I can see this but send me to my Index.php

Comment: If I use WP_Query my links are empty I don't know... it's like I've only one post when I've three @PieterGoosen

Comment: Yes, I wrote the code in the question....If I use WP_Query, I can see two posts but never give me the link for previous/next posts....

Comment: Your structure seems a bit messed up to me and your question is a bit clearer now. First of all, don't use a custom query at all. Use the main loop. Make use of `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query. Also, what is `archive-blog.php`. Please see [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/155956/31545)

Comment: Thanks for you help! I don't know the pre_get_posts function :D

Comment: My pleasure, I hope that link solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @PieterGoosen for his help, I found the solution for my problem.

In my functions.php, I construct the next function:

```
function mod_query($query){
   if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category('6')){ //My Category ID
        $query->set('posts_per_page',2);
    }

}

add_action('pre_get_posts','mod_query');
```

And I needed one file, category-blog.php where I build my html code and use the php code

```
 if (have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_posts();
        //.....my code.....
    }
 }
```

And my navigation it's works!

Thanks so much @PieterGoosen for your help.

Comment: Just check, I have edited your code. When using `pre_get_posts`, you don't need to set the `paged` parameter. You can just use the code in my edit to your answer. +1 for posting your solution :-)

Comment: I did one more edit, remember to **always** check that you are targeting the main query and that you are not on a admin pages. `pre_get_posts` alters **all** queries backend and front end. See my update. :-) Enjoy

Comment: Yes, I saw this and put in my functions.php :D Thanks for your help @PieterGoosen

Comment: My pleasure. Always glad if I can help someone. And remember to accept your own answer