# Paginating custom query on category template

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, paginate-links

I'm trying to paginate my custom post types on my category page template but for some reason when I trying to navigate to 2nd,3rd,4th etc pages it will get re-routed to the index page.
This is the function:

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
{  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  
 
     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;
 
     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   
 
     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";
 
         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
             }
         }
 
         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
```

This is the query:

```
<?php $posts = query_posts($query_string .
'&orderby=title&order=asc&post_type=images&posts_per_page=30'); ?>
```

And this is to call the function:

```
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
} ?>
```

For some reason this code works if I call the function in my page template but it doesn't work when I call it from the category template

Comment: Never use `query_posts`, alter the main query in an archive with [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), and create any additional queries with `WP_Query`.

Comment: See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)