# Set homepage to only display posts from one tag

Tags: tags, homepage

I'd like my homepage to only display posts from a single tag. Is this possible? If yes, please advise.

For instance,

> www.mysite.com/tag/sometag

will only display posts with the `sometag` tag, but how do I get www.mysite.com to automatically display only the posts seen on

> www.mysite.com/tag/sometag 
>   page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query on the home page.

With the proper conditional tags and parameters (check [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for available parameters) you can achieve what you need

You can do the following to just display posts from a given tag on your homepage

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'tag', 'SLUG_OF_TAG' );
    }
});
```

Comment: ps: I think we can simplify it further and skip `!is_admin()` here because of the `is_home` check.

Comment: @birgire I agree. The use of `!is_admin()` has become such a habit for me with `pre_get_posts`, I tend to overuse it sometimes, specially with `is_home()` checks ;-)

Comment: hehe, same with me, it's usually the first condition that I write down regardless of other conditions ;-) But sometimes I use `is_admin()` outside the callback function if I'm playing with stuff and tired of the usual `if` conditions ;-)

Comment: Hahaha, absolutely exactly the same here.

Comment: Does this work with WP version 4.9.7?  In which file (and where inside that file) do I need to add the code above?

Answer (score 0):

For that; first you have to make [Custom Page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates) and add following [loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in it and customize it in what ever way you want.

```
<?php

    $args=array(
      'tag' => 'yourtag',
      'showposts'=>5     // set number of post you want to display
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

        // display what ever you want in this post

      <?php
      endwhile;
    }
  wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

Then [create a  Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) and [select this custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Selecting_a_Page_Template) for it.

Next from settings [set this page as static home page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#WordPress_Static_Front_Page_Process) and you are ready to GO.

Comment: No, don't use a custom query.

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks for introducing some great and straight forward stuff up there.

Comment: My pleasure. For your reading, please feel free to check [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) I have done a while back regarding where to use custom queries and where not and what are the pro's and con's

Answer (score -1):

Custom wp queries will work perfectly, but in many cases pagination or a other elements gone or be "broken".

I use a not a ideal but "simplest" way: 301 redirection in Custom Page template for a orginal WP tag page.

Example piece of code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name:  Your Custom Redirect Name
 */
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: hxxp://yoursite.com/tag/your-tag-slug/");
 ?>
```