# Pagination returns 404 after page 20

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

I got a paged loop that pulls in 4 posts per page from custom post type. It works great, with the only downside that the pagination wont go over the `page/20` everything after that is 404, and the `posts_nav_link` won't show the next arrow at all. Like the pages just aren't there.

In total there are 119 published posts in the custom post type. If I change `posts_per_page` to, say 6, then I get access to more of the posts from the end, but it also stops at the `page/20`.

On the production site the pagination stops at `21`, I guess because the live database has more entries.

I got the "Blog pages show at most" setting set to 6.

Here's the loop I'm using:

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args  = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby'        => 'modified',
    'post_type'      => "projekte",
    'paged'          => $paged
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
$c = 0;
while($custom_query->have_posts()) :
    $custom_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <article>...</article>
    <?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query
?>
```

I've gone through the `functions.php` a million times looking for a some limiting `get_pre_posts` filter but there's nothing I can see.

I also got an error log setup and nothing is returned there, I've tested it that it works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do a test, add `'suppress_filters' => true,` to your arguments. This will inhibit all filters from changing your query. Just for interest sake, in which template are you doing this

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately it didn't help, but it's great that it rules the filters out. It's in `archive-projekte.php` projekte being the cpt.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you are experiencing is quite normal and expected. This is one of the big reasons I always hammer on this point, never use custom queries to replace the main query on the home page or any type of archive page. They solve one issue but creates plenty other new ones

Lets look at what you have and why you are getting these results:

### BASICS

Although you don't see the output on your archive page, the main query executes on **every** page load and returns an array of posts regardless. Removing the loop does not stop the main query from being executed. The loop just displays what is being retrieved by the main query. So what is basically happening, you are retrieving two sets of posts per page load if you replace the default loop with a custom one. The posts retrieved by the main query and posts retrieved by the custom query. If you want to test this, add the following line of code outside the loop on your archive page within php tags

```
?><pre><?php var_dump( $wp_query->posts ); ?></pre><?php
```

This will output the array of posts retrieved by the main query on that specific page

This makes custom queries very ineffecient when is replaces the main query. It is like replacing an inflated tyre which is in tip top shape with a punctured, worn tyre.

### YOUR SCENARIO

You have the following scenario

- 119 posts from your custom post type
- Posts per page option set in admin is 6
- Custom query is set to retrieve 4 posts per page

### THE MATHS

Your main query will return 20 pages which you can test with `echo $wp_query->max_num_pages;`. The maths is easy, you have 119 posts, which you can also check with `echo $wp_query->found_posts;`, posts per page is set to 6 in admin, so the ceiling of 119 / 6 = 20

As for the custom query, you can access the same info as above by changing `$wp_query` to `$custom_query`. You will see that you still have 119 posts, but you will have 30 pages due to the fact that posts per page is now set to 4. The ceiling for 119 / 4 = 30

### 404 ON PAGE 21

Whenever there are no posts to display by the main query, a 404 is triggered, and this is what you are seeing. There are enough posts to fill 20 pages, not 21 or more. So when go to page 21, the main query 404's simply because there are no more posts to display regardless if you still have plenty to display from your custom query.

I have seen posts where people say the solution is easy, simply change the amount of posts per page in the admin page to match that of your custom query.  **Don't ever do that**. Yes, it does fix the issue, but it defeats the real issue here that you should not replace the main query with a custom one. And BTW, the real solution to the problem is pretty simple, clean and is the proper correct method to achieve what you need

### WHY THE CUSTOM QUERY

You have decided to go with a custom query because of two things

- Different amount of posts per page on your custom post type archive page that the rest of the site
- Have posts sorted by date modified and not the default post date

As you can see, you have solved two issues with your custom query but have created other problems

### THE SOLUTION

This the correct, simple method to solve your issue. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query before it is executed. `pre_get_posts` alters the query variables accordingly which is used to calculated the SQL query for the specific page request.

You have to do two things here, the first would be to remove your custom query on your archive page and replace it with the default loop. Once you have done that, you will see 6 posts per page ordered by post date as it should be by default.

Now, open functions.php and use `pre_get_posts`  to correct the amount of posts per page and sort order

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) 
{
    if(    !is_admin() 
        && $q->is_main_query() 
        && $q->is_post_type_archive( 'projekte' ) 
    ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 4          );
        $q->set( 'orderby',        'modified' );
    }
});
```

You should now see 4 posts per page ordered by modified date, correctly paged on your custom post type archive page `projekte`

### EXTRA READING

You should also read the following post I had done on a similar issue a while ago, and all the posts I have linked to in that specific post

- [When to make use of a custom query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

### EDIT

For those stuck with the dinosaur php versions which does not support closures, here is the fall back version of the `pre_get_posts` action

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse176347_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse176347_pre_get_posts( $q ) 
{
    if(    !is_admin() 
        && $q->is_main_query() 
        && $q->is_post_type_archive( 'projekte' ) 
    ) {
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 4          );
        $q->set( 'orderby',        'modified' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Epic answer :) I've known of `pre_get_posts` post but not to this depth. Thanks for explaining! The anonymous function is a nice touch also.

Comment: Glad my answer helped. Enjoy :-)

Comment: The server seems to run a really old PHP, so the anonymous functions gives an error. It's an easy fix though.

Comment: Strange that some servers still uses php versions prior to 5.4. Support for 5.3 has recently been dropped, so servers still using 5.2 (which you are using) and 5.3 poses security risks

Comment: Totally agree, for this project it's out of my hands :(

Comment: Means you are stuck with the old ways. Good luck on this project :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Epic answer. Wish I could give it more than just +1.

Comment: @m0r7if3r Thanks for your comment. Appreciated :-)