# Not getting posts of custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types

I  have created a custom template and trying to get a custom post of type "song", But it is displaying only the header and footer on the page. There is no post content coming. Even if I try to call general posts then also no content coming, Should I register this template anywhere in the theme? OR need to call anything here?

My code :

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: song Page
 *
 * Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div>

<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
   while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_post(); 
      query_posts( 'post_type=song'); 
   } // end while
} // end if
?></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Please help to correct my code. I want to display all posts of custom post type "songs".
I have already created a custom post type.

I am putting the above code in WordPress editor, I have installed a plugin called "PHP execution" so it executes PHP code.

Comment: Is this part of an archive page for the custom post type?

Comment: I want to display all posts of custom post type "songs". Where do you want to display these posts?

Comment: @PieterGoosen - Yes I have accepted.

Comment: @BradDalton - There is custom template I have created. as a code in that template , I have call header , footer and above loop to get posts of custom type , But in page only header and footer comes :(

Comment: @MannyFleurmond - No...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have two major flaws in your code:

- `query_posts` needs to go before your loop, not inside it
- Never use `query_posts` in the first place unless you need to break something on your page

To learn why not to use `query_posts` and when to use a custom query and how to use it, check [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) I have done a while ago

So, in order to correct your code in your template, we are going to make use of `WP_Query` and **not** `query_posts`, and we are going to do the query **before** the loop

Try something like this:

```
<?php 
 /* Template Name: song Page
 *
 * Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div>

    <?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'song'
    );
    $q = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
            $q->the_post(); 

            //Add your template tags like below
            the_title();

        } // end while
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } // end if
    ?>

</div>
```

Also, never forget to reset custom queries if you have used the loop or `setup_postdata($post)` with `wp_reset_postdata()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer , Using above code I am getting just post name , But I need to display post title with thumbnail and little content, so May I need to call the_content()?

Comment: Yes, you should add whatever you need to, this is just the basics. for content, you will need to add `the_content();`. You still need to add all your HTML mark up as well. This section is personal preference, something I can't help you with :-)

Comment: For basic template outlay, have a look at the bundled themes like twentyfifteen. This should give you a good starting point

Comment: How can I call default post css style for this custom post? I just want that my custom post also should display proper like normal post in terms of style/css.

Comment: Just copy your loop between the while part from your index.php and add it in the loop here. As I said, that is a personal preference section which you will need to sort out yourself unfortunately. I can never know your theme styles. That is why this section is off topic here :-)

Comment: Okay...Let me try..:)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create any templates if you simply want to list all pages in an archive for your custom post type:

You simply go to http://example.com/songs and WordPress will display all your CPT pages in a standard archive according to the Template Hierarchy. Swap out example.com with your domain.

You may need to re-save your Permalinks to flush your rewrite rules and include the following parameters in your register_post_type function:

```
'has_archive' => true,

'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'songs', 'with_front' => false ),
```

If you want to create a custom page for your CPT archive, create a new file and name it archive-song.php in the root directory of your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***Settings > Permalinks*** and just click on "**Save Changes**" button.
Now refresh the page.

Answer (score -1):

Or even

```
query_posts( 'post_type=song');
```

Comment: Could you add more explanation on why this would work or why this is an answer to the question?

Comment: I just meant try 'post_type=song' instead of 'post_type=songs'
Sorry for confusion

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried `'post_type'=> 'songs'`?

Reference: [Querying by Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Querying_by_Post_Type)