# Incorrect posts displayed on category page

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I'm using this loop to show my 5 latest posts but even if I'm selecting a category it still shows the 5 latest posts from all category.

```
query_posts('showposts=5');
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                <h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
                <p><?php the_content('Read More..'); ?></p>
                <br/>
                <hr> 
                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I show the 5 latest posts when it loads the index page and load the latest 5 post from a category when the user selects a category?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, never ever make use of `query_posts`. It is not just slow and reruns queries, but it breaks pagination, page functionalities and the globals like `$post` on which some theme functionalities and plugins rely. If you really need to run custom queries (which is totally unnecessary in this case), make use of `WP_Query` or `get_posts`.

All your template files should have the same basic setup, the loop, which should look like this

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        // Template tags and HTML mark up

    }
}
```

No custom queries, no `query_posts`. The correct poss will be displayed according to the template and page being displayed. If you are on a category page, only posts will be displayed from the selected category. In your code, this line stuffs up everything and should be removed from all template files:

```
query_posts('showposts=5');
```

By removing this, all your templates should display what they are suppose to show. If you need to alter anything on your template pages, use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query before it is executed.

### REFERENCE

- [Some doubts about the main query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)