# What is the difference between $paged and $page?

Tags: pages, pagination, paged, split

I'm creating pagination for my site. Hope everyone can explain to me what below code used for? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}
query_posts('paged='.$paged.'&posts_per_page=');
?>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I hope you understand what query variables is. If not, here is it in short. The main query uses `WP_Query` to set itself up. In the main query, `WP_Query` uses public query variables to construct the main query according to the page being requested, and `paged` and `page` are two of them. To see all the public query variables, paste this in your header and check on all templates how this are set according to the queried page

```
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

The function [`get_query_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) is used to get the values from those public query variables, and in this case that is `page` and `paged`.

To answer your question, these two parameters and its values are used by `WP_Query` to calculate pagination and more importantly the offset of posts according to page numbers. It is this parameter that ensures that your posts page correctly when paging through pages

- `paged` -> Used on the homepage, blogpage, archive pages and pages to calculate pagination. 1st page is `0` and from there the number correspond to the page number
- `page` -> Use on a static front page and single pages for pagination. Pagination on these pages works the same, a static front page is treated as single page on pagination. By pagination on single pages, I mean that single posts can be broken down into multiple pages

What your code basically does is, it checks if the `paged` parameter is set, if that fails, it checks whether the `page` parameter is set, and if that is not set, set the page to `1`. This check will always fail on page 1, so `$paged` will always fall back to `1`. On any other page than page one, either `paged` or `page` will return true and sets `$paged` to the correct page number

Final note: Never ever use `query_posts` unless you need to break something on your page, and believe you me, you don't want that. Always use `WP_Query` for paginated custom queries. For a full explanation on this, please see [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) I have done a while ago

Comment: Thank @pieter-goosen It's really nice explanation. Is `paged` used to get current page which viewing?

Comment: Yes, you can use `echo get_query_var( 'paged' );` to get the current pagenumber you are viewing

Comment: Great explanation! The `page` param takes the `<!--nextpage-->` keyword into account, which breaks up a single post into multiple pages: https://en.support.wordpress.com/nextpage/view-all/

Comment: Be aware that a homepage can be set to a static front page and then page is used instead of paged.

@PieterGoosen
I don't agree to your final note.
If you return posts via a shortcode query_posts could be used.
Regradless if you do this or not you have to call wp_reset_query after you have fetched the data otherwise you will run into trouble.
I actually do this and haven't had problems at all.