# Invalid previous pagination links generated from paginate_links()

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

I inherited this WordPress project and it is part of a live Website. The original author wrote a custom pagination function that is being used more than once on the Website. However, on a few pages, it simply doesn't work.

This is the function (it's ugly, but it looks fine to me)

```
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {

  if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
  }

  /**
   * This first part of our function is a fallback
   * for custom pagination inside a regular loop that
   * uses the global $paged and global $wp_query variables.
   *
   * It's good because we can now override default pagination
   * in our theme, and use this function in default quries
   * and custom queries.
   */
  global $paged;
  if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
  }
  if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$numpages) {
        $numpages = 1;
    }
  }

  /**
   * We construct the pagination arguments to enter into our paginate_links
   * function.
   */
  $pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => '%_%',
    'format'          => '?paged=%#%',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => True,
    'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
    'type'            => 'array',
    'add_args'        => true,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
  );

  $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

  if (is_array($paginate_links)) {
    echo '<ul class="pagination">';
    foreach ( $paginate_links as $page ) {
      echo "<li>$page</li>";
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}
```

and is being called like this everywhere it is used

```
<?php custom_pagination($query->max_num_pages,"",$paged); ?>
```

The links being constructed look fine

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><span class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
  <li><a class="page-numbers" href="?paged=2">2</a></li>
  <li><a class="page-numbers" href="?paged=3">3</a></li>
  <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="?paged=2">»</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, clicking on page 2 or 3 redirects to `http://domain.com/paged/2/`, for example. Then, the generated pagination looks like this :

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a class="prev page-numbers" href="">«</a></li>
  <li><a class="page-numbers" href="">1</a></li>
  <li><span class="page-numbers current">2</span></li>
  <li><a class="page-numbers" href="?paged=3">3</a></li>
  <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="?paged=3">»</a></li>
</ul>
```

Notice how the previous pages links are wrong? How do I fix this?

### update

Also, when hovering over the first page link, the URL shows `http://domain.com/paged/2/` (i.e. because of `href=""`), but hovering over page 3, it shows `http://domain.com/paged/2/?paged=3`.

That's not right.

### Update 2

Before you mention it, yes, I did update the permalinks, many times.

Comment: Since it only happens on a few pages, it may be a product of the original author not taking into account [the `page` query var in addition to `paged`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180784/what-is-the-difference-between-paged-and-page). What does the logic which sets up the `$paged` variable that's passed to the function look like?