# Wordpress Pagination not working, any ideas?

Tags: pagination

So I've been looking into why the pagination isn't working, but I just can't find anything. When it goes to page 2, it just shows the same as the first page. Any other ideas?

```
    <?php  global $paged; get_template_part( 'template-parts/header'); 
    if ( $total > 1 )  {
         // get the current page
         if ( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
              $current_page = 1;
         // structure of "format" depends on whether we're using pretty permalinks
         if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
             $format = '?paged=%#%';
         }
         }
     ?>
<div class="blog-inner">
      <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-x">
          <div class="large-8 column">
            <?php
              if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
                 $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
                 $paged = get_query_var('page');
                } else {
                 $paged = 1;
                }

              $blogs = array(
                'post_type'      => 'post',
                'order'      => 'DESC',
                'posts_per_page' =>  3,
                'paged'      => $paged
              );

              $blog_posts = new WP_Query($blogs); ?>
            <?php if ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) : $blog_posts->the_post(); ?>
              <div class="blog-post">
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <div class="byline">

                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                  ?>
                </div>
                <div class="read-all">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="">Read The Post</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <div class="pagination">
              <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                  <?php 
                      echo paginate_links( array(
                          'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                          'total'        => $blog_posts->max_num_pages,
                          'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                          'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
                          'show_all'     => false,
                          'type'         => 'plain',
                          'end_size'     => 2,
                          'mid_size'     => 1,
                          'prev_next'    => true,
                          'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
                          'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
                          'add_args'     => false,
                          'add_fragment' => '',
                      ) );
                  ?>
              </div>

            <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[some html-taken out, so some divs might not match up]

More Info: it is currently set as the index.php page, even though it's not the home page. if you get to it through misspelling a url, it works

Comment: Describe “not working”

Comment: @Milo when it goes to the second page, it shows the same pages as the first page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @lukepnnngtn and welcome! Prepare yourself for reading.

Since you're working on the `index.php` file we need to consider what's said in the docs under **Removing query_posts from the Main Loop** in the Pagination Codex ([link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Removing_query_posts_from_the_Main_Loop)):

> For example, let's say your theme queries the main loop like this on
>   your home page (index.php) and category pages (category.php) and the
>   pagination is not working...

What you need to do is to remove the `WP_Query()` from the `index.php` file and make an action in the `function.php`. It's described beat by beat in the link but I will paste it here too:

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {
  // do not alter the query on wp-admin pages and only alter it if it's the main query
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){

    // alter the query for the home and category pages 

    if(is_home()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    }

    if(is_category()){
      $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    }

  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
```

After that we need to go back to the `index.php` file. At this point it should look something like this:

```
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();

    ...

endwhile;

global $wp_query;

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
    'total'         => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'current'       => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'format'        => '?paged=%#%',
    'show_all'      => false,
    'type'          => 'plain',
    'end_size'      => 2,
    'mid_size'      => 1,
    'prev_next'     => true,
    'prev_text'     => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
    'next_text'     => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
    'add_args'      => false,
    'add_fragment'  => '',
) );
```

I looked into your code some more and I also suggest reading WordPress' documentation on ([get_query_var()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)):

> For getting the current pagination number on a static front page (Page
>   template) you have to use the 'page' query variable...

After some more research, I found this answer ([link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180784/what-is-the-difference-between-paged-and-page#answer-180785)) on another WP related question that reads:

> - paged -> Used on the homepage, blogpage, archive pages and pages to calculate pagination. 1st page is 0 and from there the number corresponds to the page number
> - page -> Use on a static front page and single pages for pagination.    Pagination on these pages works the same, a static front page is treated as a single page on pagination.

This is straight from the docs ([link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Static_Front_Page)):

> If the pagination is broken on a static front page you have to add the
>   "paged" parameter this way...

So what you did here is great:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
}
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
}
else {
    $paged = 1;
}
```

Your code was working just fine when I used it on a `static page` with a custom template up until the moment I made it Homepage, then you need to use the `$paged` variable for the `current` argument in the `paginate_links()` call, like this:

```
paginate_links( array(
    ...
    'current'       => max( 1, $paged ),
    ...
) );
```

I still can't ask questions in the comments so I hope I was helpful. Good luck!