# Custom taxonomy pagination

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pagination

I'm creating custom numbered pagination for custom taxonomy archive page.
So, I have no problem with displaying pagination, with proper links display, etc.

However, when I click a link above page number 2 (e.g. page 3, like:

> `my-website.com/page/3/?my_category=some-term`

i get 404 - page does not exist.

The category contains over 60 posts, and there should be 8 pages, but
only the first and second one are displayed properly

> `my-website.com/?my_category=some-term`

and

> `my-website.com/page/2/?my_category=some-term`

but everything above this gives 404.

This is my WP_Query in this taxonomy template:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$qobj = get_queried_object();

$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 8,
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'tax_query' => array(
       array(
          'taxonomy' => $qobj->taxonomy,
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => $qobj->term_id
       )
  ),
  'paged' => $paged
);
```

and

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop your custom query and go back to the default loop. Never replace the main query on the home page or any kind of archive page with a custom query. Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query variables before the main query runs

Your taxonomy archive page should look like this

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        // Your markup and template tags

    }
}
```

Comment: Ill accept this after I test it.
Would youcare to elaborate why this is - why custom query is a bad idea?

Comment: You should read [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545). I have explained everything in there. Hope that will answer your question beter :-). Enjoy