# Is it possible to add query parameters on the archive page?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, query

I have a custom post type 'Works', and an archive page 'archive-works.php'. I would like to hide the non-public posts from the archive page, so I added a custom meta box.

I also modified the query to list the posts only, when the public_s is not 0:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'public_s',
    'meta_value'   => '0',
    'meta_compare' => '!='
);
$queryWorks = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $queryWorks->have_posts() ) : while ( $queryWorks->have_posts() ) : $queryWorks->the_post();
```

For some reasons the query doesn't work.

```
var_dump($queryWorks->the_post()); -> NULL
```

What's the problem with the query?

Comment: Why aren't you using the built in "private"  functionality?

Comment: Good idea, I forgot to use that. I used this method on the whole site, and in the functions and it's too much time to replace everywhere. I think it's easier to fix the query. I hope you have an idea. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @s_ha_dum already pointed out, you can use the built-in private posts status function when publishing posts. This will hide these posts from all logged out users.

As you have already gone down the custom fields route, you can make the following changes to your custom post type archive

- Remove your custom query. This messes up page functionalities and pagination. I have written [an answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) on this a while ago on where to use custom queries and where not
- Use `pre_get_posts` as described in my linked post to alter the main query accordingly. This will solve all your issues.

***NOTE:*** By default, the `post_type` used by `WP_Query` is `post`. You probably have no default posts which fits your query, that is why you don't get any posts

You need to do something like this in functions.php after reverting to the default loop in your post type archive page:

***NOTE:*** Only sample code, adjust as needed. Requires PHP 5.3+)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) 
{
    if ( !is_admin() // VERY important, targets only front end queries
         && $q->is_main_query() // VERY important, targets only main query
         && $q->is_post_type_archive( 'YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME' ) 
         // Which post type archive page to target.
         // for example: && $q->is_post_type_archive( 'works' )
    ) {
        $q->set( 'meta_key', 'META_KEY_NAME' ); 
        //for example: $q->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );
        $q->set( 'meta_value', 'META_VALUE_VALUE');
        // Rest of your arguments to set
    }
});
```