# Display taxonomy posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

This seems super basic but cant find a clear answer anywhere. All I am looking for is the loop to display posts within a taxonomy.

Say I have a custom taxonomy called `custom_category` and within that I have a few categories like US and Canada and then Idaho and Washington being children of US. So the url would look like `http://example.com/custom_category/us/idaho/`. All I am looking to do is add the correct PHP to the `taxonomy.php` page to show the posts within each category. So you only see posts attached to Idaho when you are on that page, and Washington when on that page.

I don't want to add specific queries for each category since if I add a new state, I don't want to add a new custom template.

Answer (score 0):

If your URL structure is valid and correct, all you need then is the default loop.

The main query runs on each and every page request, and the parameters passed to `WP_Query` ( *yes, the main query also uses `WP_Query`*) is determined by the URL and rewrite rules for that specific page. If your URL structure is a valid structure and matches a true page request for a taxonomy term page, then the posts returned by main query should match and all be in the specific term requested via the URL.

I have done a post on when to use custom queries and when not, you can go read that post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545). This is very important to know, and I cannot stres this enough, never ever use custom queries in place of the main query on the home page and any type of archive page. Custom queries are not just ineffecient when use instead of the main query, but it breaks page functuionality.

To wrap up, the only code you need in your taxonomy template is the following

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

        // Your template tags and markup like

        the_title();

    }
}
```