# Pagination with custom field

Tags: customization, pagination

I've got a little (big) problem.

Is there a solution to show only posts that have not the same custom field value (from a specific custom field key) ?

I have some post with a manual ID as custom field, and I don't want to show them into my loop, and keep a good pagination.

It's easy to skip this post (that have the same manual ID) but I cannot get a good pagination because I use `continue;` to skip them.

Comment: `pre_get_posts` with a `meta_query`. There are many examples on site, just use the site search. :-)

Comment: Okay, I have already look at this. But I don't know which custom field value I have to exclude before the loop so I cannot use this...

Comment: How are you creating the custom field?

Comment: When I make a post I add a Custom field (key = Custom_ID, value = manual). This custom field can be the same for different post.
I use a custom post like this to recognize same post in different state (<=> same content but with a little difference, for example not the same categories).

Comment: Now, I don't want to show more then one post that contain the same Custom_ID. I already done this like this : http://pastebin.com/feQtFYwC. But in archive page I have a pagination problem ... ((( Sorry for double post, I cannot edit after 5 mins, I don't know yet all rules here, sorry about that..)))

Comment: Just one request, file an [edit] and add all code directly in your question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in comments, you need [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and a [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to exclude posts from a certain custom field with a certain value from the main query. It is really in your best interest to read up on the before mentioned. Just remember, all parameters in `WP_Query` works on `pre_get_posts` as `WP_Query` uses `pre_get_posts` to alter the query parameters, and the main query uses `WP_Query`

In short, you can try the following: (*REQUIRES PHP 5.4+ and the code is untested*)

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (     !is_admin() // Targets the front end only, we don't need this for is_home()
          && $q->is_home() // Change this to the appropriate page, here we only target the home page
          && $q->is_main_query() // Target the main query only
    ) {
        $meta_query = [
            [
                'key' => 'Custom_ID',
                'compare' => 'NOT IN' // Do not get posts from this spoecific key/value pair
            ]
        ];
        $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you firstly, you are helpfull. Sorry for incomprehension.. When I said "manual" that's mean that I add mannualy a key (-> like '32555', or '32999' for example). But I'll test this, your code can alter the wp_query loop after each iteration, is it this ?

Comment: I have updated the code to include all values from the custom field. This will only work for the main query, not for custom queries. On what page do you need to use this exactly. You should not run custom queries unnecessarily.

Comment: In my home page I use the pastebin code above, it's working good, no need more.Now, let's check that we are in the same wave length (french expression, I hope it's the same in english haha) : https://s3.amazonaws.com/aww-imagedata/52ee5452-d7cc-4c2d-97df-ad26c78a0f7c.png . Like you see, skip post is not a problem, but keep pagination is really hard.. I have this problem into archive / category page, but I'll use a custom search page, and I'll need a custom query here too... I hope you understand me, because I'm not the best english speaker man in the world like you can see.. :/

Comment: You should not be using custom queries as your main loop, this is always a problem in many ways, switch back to the default loop. As for the other pages, just extend the action's condition to include those pages. I'm off to bed now as it is quite late, but take your time and work though [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545), it should clear up a few things for you ;-). Good luck

Comment: Thank you for advise Pieter, good night, maybe see you soon !

Comment: I still cannot resolve my problem, I will try a custom sql request instead to get correctly my posts so..