# How to display all posts from standard posts to custom post types in a loop with pagination?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, pagination

I have several standard posts and posts from a custom posts type. Now I want to display all of them on my home page using a loop. My problem is that it displays the posts including the posts from the custom post type, but not all.

Types of posts I have right now: **7 standard posts**, **15 Photos**, **5 Videos**, **2 Webs**. Total of **29 posts**.

In my Reading settings, I have set the blogs pages to show at most to **6 posts**. Now when I go to the home page, I can see those 6 posts mixed with different post types but there are only 2 pages (the 2nd page also consist of 6 posts). Meaning, there are only less than 13 posts where it actuality, I have 29 total posts. When I go to **website.com/page/3/** I get a 404 error.

I am using the latest [FoundationPress](https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress) framework for my WordPress theme and here's my code

```
    <?php 
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $loop = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => array('post', 'photo', 'video', 'web'),
            'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
            'paged' => $paged
        ));
    ?>

        <?php while ( $loop -> have_posts() ) : $loop -> the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Just for reference, here's the FoundationPress function to show the navigation

```
$paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', html_entity_decode( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'mid_size' => 5,
    'prev_next' => true,
    'prev_text' => __( '&laquo;', 'foundationpress' ),
    'next_text' => __( '&raquo;', 'foundationpress' ),
    'type' => 'list',
) );
```

Comment: Use [`pre_get_posts`](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts&ved=0ahUKEwi8g8bx0LrKAhWKaRQKHbNrA0UQFggZMAA&usg=AFQjCNGqrm7Iu558AtjXbbFNdaE2xiqGxg) to alter the main query. Drop the custom query

Comment: Sadly, this is the only time I have read about pre_get_posts, but this seems to be the answer.

Comment: Then you would find [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) very useful. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom query to include CPTs in homepage posts in normal cases. Just use `pre_get_posts`.

```
function wpse215208_include_all_cpt( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'photo', 'video', 'web' ) );
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse215208_include_all_cpt');
```

Comment: I'm having an error on your code `Fatal error: Call to a member function is_main_query() on a non-object on line 4`

Comment: @user1874974 My bad, missed the argument in callback. This is what happens when you type in hurry. I have fixed the code. Please try now.

Comment: Sweet! Works like a charm. I have never heard about this pre_get_posts until now and it saved me tons. thanks!