# Query posts according to specific post meta values

Tags: query, post-meta, meta-value

I have a loop in my index.php for my home page like this...

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

I have a function to query the posts by ascending date...

```
function order_home_asc($query) {
  if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('orderby', 'date');
    $query->set('order', 'asc');
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'order_home_asc');
```

I've been told the above is the best way to query the posts.

I now want to query those posts by a specific post meta key('job_status') and value('open') as well as by date and asc.

I tried this but it didn't work...

```
function order_home_asc($query) {
  if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
    $query->set('orderby', 'date');
    $query->set('order', 'asc');
    $query->set('meta_query, array( 
    array( 'key', 'job_status', 'value', open, 'compare', '!=' )
    )
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'order_home_asc');
```

If there's an easier/simpler solution without the need for a function that would be great.

Would this be better as my loop?

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title', 'meta-key' => 'job_status','meta_value' => 'open' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
        <?php the_title(); ?>   
<?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is complete wrong in your `meta_query`. A key/value pair in an array should be in the format of `'key' => 'value'`. Your format is `'key', 'value'` which in context of an array translate to `0 => 'key', 1 => 'value'`. That is why your `meta_query` does not work.

Your failure is also due to not very good housekeeping. As your `meta_query` is written, it is hard to properly read it and because of that you miss obvious bugs.

Lets rewrite that section in a more readable way

```
$meta_query = [
    [
        'key'     => 'job_status',
        'value'   => 'open',
        'compare' => '!='
    ]
];
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

As you can see, my code is easy to read, and very easy to spot obvious bug.

### EDIT

If you need to add another key/value pair in your `meta_query`, you can simply just add another array.

```
$meta_query = [
    [
        'key'     => 'job_status',
        'value'   => 'open',
        'compare' => '!='
    ],
    [
        'key'     => 'another key',
        'value'   => 'another value',
        'compare' => '!='
    ]
];
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

Comment: So is this method of querying posts via a function the best way?

Comment: Yes, `pre_get_posts` is the correct and recommended way of altering the main query. You should avoid using any type of custom query (*custom loop*) to replace the main query with. You should take your time and work through [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) in which I explained everything in detail ;-)

Comment: And lastly, if I wanted to query the posts with more than 1 key/value would it just be a matter of adding the extra lines?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Enjoy ;-)