# Style first 3 posts differently and use a 2nd loop to get rest of posts / offset and pagination broken

Tags: loop, pagination, offsets

I'm working on a theme and I am having trouble with loops/pagination breaks when using an offest. I looked online and tried to use only 1 loop ([per this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217618/two-custom-loops-pagination-offset)) but I'm having trouble making it work.

I want to have the first 3 posts at the top of the page be the most recent (post 1-3), and then bottom 3 posts to be the next 3 (post 4-6), when you click on the pagination I want it to be at the top (post 1-3), and posts (7-9).

Right now the code works where it shows up properly on the first page, but when I click "back" on the pagination it just shows the exact same 6 posts over and over again on each previous page.

See my code for my Index page below:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="row post-carousel">
<?php
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
    );

    $query = new WP_query ( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>

<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); /* start the loop */ ?>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'most-recent' ); ?>>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="post-thumbnail-img"><?php the_post_thumbnail('index-carousel'); ?></div>

        </a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>


</article><!-- #post-## -->
</div>

<?php // End the loop.
endwhile;

rewind_posts();

} ?>
</div>

<div class="row newsletter-container">
<div class="newsletter col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <p>Sign up for my newsletter, for all the latest updates!</p>
</div>
<div class="newsletter col-sm-12 col-md-6">

<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<!-- code goes here -->
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->

</div>
</div>


    <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=3&offset=3');
        if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
                /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php _tk_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Also, when I try to use the PHP alternative syntax for control structures, it just seems to break the code and the whole page goes white.

Adding in the navigation code as well:

```
if ( ! function_exists( '_tk_content_nav' ) ) :
/**
 * Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable
 */
function _tk_content_nav( $nav_id ) {
    global $wp_query, $post;

    // Don't print empty markup on single pages if there's nowhere to navigate.
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $previous = ( is_attachment() ) ? get_post( $post->post_parent ) : get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
        $next = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );

        if ( ! $next && ! $previous )
            return;
    }

    // Don't print empty markup in archives if there's only one page.
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages < 2 && ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) )
        return;

    $nav_class = ( is_single() ) ? 'post-navigation' : 'paging-navigation';

    ?>
    <nav role="navigation" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $nav_id ); ?>" class="<?php echo $nav_class; ?>">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', '_tk' ); ?></h1>
        <ul class="pager">

        <?php if ( is_single() ) : // navigation links for single posts ?>

            <?php previous_post_link( '<li class="nav-previous previous">%link</li>', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', '_tk' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?>
            <?php next_post_link( '<li class="nav-next next">%link</li>', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', '_tk' ) . '</span>' ); ?>

        <?php elseif ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) ) : // navigation links for home, archive, and search pages ?>

            <?php if ( get_next_posts_link() ) : ?>
            <li class="nav-previous previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', '_tk' ) ); ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) : ?>
            <li class="nav-next next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', '_tk' ) ); ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </ul>
    </nav><!-- #<?php echo esc_html( $nav_id ); ?> -->
    <?php
}
endif; // _tk_content_nav
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to never use [**`query_posts`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/). Instead use a custom query or the [**`pre_get_posts`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook for both instances and always make sure you call `wp_reset_postdata` after your custom query.

**BUT** becase your nav function references the `global $wp_query`, you would have to use `query_posts` passing the `paged` parameter to it.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="row post-carousel">
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
        );

        $query = new WP_query ( $args );
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>

            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); /* start the loop */ ?>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'most-recent' ); ?>>
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <div class="post-thumbnail-img"><?php the_post_thumbnail('index-carousel'); ?></div>

                            </a>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>


                    </article><!-- #post-## -->
                </div>

            <?php // End the loop.
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();

        } ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row newsletter-container">
        <div class="newsletter col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            <p>Sign up for my newsletter, for all the latest updates!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="newsletter col-sm-12 col-md-6">

            <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
            <!-- code goes here -->
            <!--End mc_embed_signup-->

        </div>
    </div>


<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$second_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'offset' => 3,
    'paged' => $paged
);
query_posts($second_args);
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
         * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
         */
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php _tk_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I tried this and the pagination still doesn't work. It still pulls up the same posts as the first page when I go to previous posts... any idea of how to fix the pagination issue?

Comment: Just searched for your nav function and can see it's referencing the `global $wp_query`. Updated my answer

Comment: Hmm, I updated the code with your updates and it's still not working. I included the pagination code above on my original question. Would I need to change anything on there?

Answer (score 0):

May be too Late but still I think this code will work for you.

```
<?php
    if( !is_paged() ){ // Condition for Checking is it Blog Listing Page 1 or not if yes then True
        $homepagePosts = new WP_Query(array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 )); // Custom Condition for adding only Fresh Post
            while ($homepagePosts->have_posts()) {
                $homepagePosts->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="clearfix mt-4 mb-4 wrapper">
                    <div class="clearfix single-post">
                        <div class="fl single-post-img">
                            <div class="blogthumb">
                                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
                                    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'singplepost' ); ?>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>      
                        </div>
                        <div class="fl single-post-content">
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <span class="d-block position-relative mb-2"><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 18); ?></span>
                            <span class="small" style="color:#888"><?php echo get_the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></span>
                        </div>      
                    </div>
                </div>
    <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?> 

<?php } ?>
<!-- One Big Post -->

<!-- Remaining All Posts -->
<div class="clearfix wrapper">
    <div class="clearfix authorpostcontainer">
        <?php
        $current_page = get_query_var('paged');
        $current_page = max( 1, $current_page );
        $per_page = 9;
        $offset_start = 1;
        $offset = ( $current_page - 1 ) * $per_page + $offset_start;
        $post_list = new WP_Query(array(
            'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
            'paged'          => $current_page,
            'offset'         => $offset, // Starts with the second most recent post.
        ));

        // Manually count the number of pages, because we used a custom OFFSET (i.e.
        // other than 0), so we can't simply use $post_list->max_num_pages or even
        // $post_list->found_posts without extra work/calculation.
        $total_rows = max( 0, $post_list->found_posts - $offset_start );
        $total_pages = ceil( $total_rows / $per_page );

        if ( $post_list->have_posts() ):
            while ( $post_list->have_posts() ):
                $post_list->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="one-third fl blogbox">
                <div class="blogthumb">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
                        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'newpost' ); ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>              
                    <div class="blogdetails">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="posttitle"><?php the_title(); ?></a>               
                        <span class="postdate"><?php echo get_the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></span><!--&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<php $current_cat_id = the_category_ID(false); ?><a href='<php echo get_category_link($current_cat_id); ?>' class="catlink"><php echo get_cat_name($current_cat_id); ?></a-->
                    </div>              
                </div>
            <?php
            endwhile;
            endif;
            wp_reset_postdata();    
        ?>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="clearfix wrapper mt-4 mb-4 text-center">
    <?php
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'total'   => $total_pages,
            'current' => $current_page,
        ) );
    ?>
</div>
<!-- Remaining All Posts -->
```