# Does wp_query and query_posts affect website performance?

Tags: php, wp-query, query, query-posts

I've been aware about the difference of wp_query and query_posts. I just want to know what impact does both query methods to the performance of the page? Which query method makes the page load quicker or slower?

Comment: See my answer in the duplicate. I wrote an extensive answer on this

Comment: Also, you have to read [my answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

Comment: Hi, you again @pieter. you've been helping me a lot. Well, i just don't understand one thing, Should i use get_posts or wp_query for maximizing load performance?

Comment: `get_posts` are meant for non paginated queries as it breaks pagination (*legally*). That is why it is faster than a normal `WP_Query`. If you look at the source of `get_posts`, this is achieved by passing `'no_found_rows' => true` to `WP_Query`. So to answer your comment, if you need a non paginated query, use `get_posts` or `WP_Query`, but then remember to pass `'no_found_rows' => true` as an argument to `WP_Query`. The effect will be the same. For paginated queries, never use `get_posts`, use `WP_query`

Comment: Ok, That's great to know. Thank you again, @pieter. So if i use get_posts to fetch an image url for the post's banner, it will be faster than using wp_query? and also, does get_posts uses the same arguments as wp_query?

Comment: *So if i use get_posts to fetch an image url for the post's banner, it will be faster than using wp_query* Yes, although I'm a bit lost in your usecase here. If you really need the custom query, yes, use `get_posts`. If you are not sure about correctly getting the image, like if you think you are doing it wrong, feel free to post a new question with the exact details of exactly what you want to do plus the code you are using. You can pass any valid parameter in `WP_Query` to `get_posts`. I always ignore the `get_posts` parameters as they are turned into valid `WP_Query` parameters

Comment: Thank you. I think it is more clear now to me. Thank you again for a million time, @pieter. :) I have this post under two different taxonomies, so i need to get the post. But i tried using get_posts and it works too. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question was answered a few times on this site. Have a look at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/68682)

Comment: Please mark the question as duplicate. Do not post links as answers