# 2 Loops on one page - pagination of 2nd loop ignore array of excluded posts

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

I have 2 loop on one page. First one shows 11 recent posts in rand order and pushes each post ID into `do_not_duplicate`array.

```
$argsRandom = array(
  'numberposts' => 11,
  'fields'      => 'ids'
);

$latest_posts =  get_posts( $argsRandom );
shuffle( $latest_posts );

$counter = 0;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 11, 
    'post__in' => $latest_posts , 
    'orderby' => 'post__in', 
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;

while ($loop-> have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
```

Second one should show all posts omitting those in `do_not_duplicate`. It works fine on first page but something strange happens on `/page/3/` which shows last 3 post and all of them are from `do_not_duplicate` array. Can't figure out why is that.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args2 = array(
    'posts_per_page' =>11,
    'post__not_in' => $do_not_duplicate,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
    );


$loop2 = new WP_Query($args2);
while ($loop2-> have_posts()) : $loop2->the_post();
```

I'm working on index page and run first loop only on `!is_paged()`

Comment: where you put `wp_reset_query` ?

Comment: You should not be running a custom query for your main loop on the home page or any type of archive page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is suppose to be the main loop on your home page, there is a far better way to achieve this without running any custom query at all. You should never replace the main query with a custom one. I'm not going to go into details as I have already done a [quite extensive answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) on this which you must go and read.

We can use the main query and modify it to our free will to adjust it to what we need throught the filters and actions available

### THE MASTER PLAN - The lego parts

You need 22 posts on page one, and from there on just 11. The tricky parts are

- Page 1 where we need the first 11 posts in random order, then the next 11 in normal order.
- Recalculating pagination as we will have the last page 404'ing in most cases depending on post count

What we need to do is:

- Most important, remove the custom queries and go back to the main loop on `index.php`. Your `index.php` should look like the following: (*Adjust to your exact needs, this is the bare minimum*)

  ```
  if ( have_posts() ) {
      while ( have_posts() ) {
          the_post();

          // Your markup and template tags to display posts

      } 
      // Your paging function
  } else {
      // Your message to display when there is no posts
  }
  ```
- Set posts per page to 11. We can do that manually or use the setting in the backend
- Through `pre_get_posts` we will add an extra 11 posts to page 11. At this stage you should have 22 posts on page one, sorted by date. The other pages should have 11 posts with most probably the last page 404'ing.
- To sort out pagination, we will need to filter the amount of found posts through the `found_posts` filter. The `$max_num_pages` property in the query object, which is responsible for calulating pagination, uses the amount of posts per page and the amount of found posts to calculate how many pages there will be. After this is sorted, everything will work, except the first 11 posts on page one which will not be random
- To randomize the first 11 posts on page one, we will rearrange the post order of the posts through the `the_posts` filter. This filter executes before the loop is actually run to display the posts. After this is done, you should have the result you are after

### THE CODE - Putting our lego blocks to use

**Few notes**

- All code is <strike>un</strike>tested <strike>and</strike> but might still be buggy. Please let me know if you have any issues
- The code requires at least PHP 5.4
- Adjust as needed. All code will go into a custom plugin (*recommended*) or in your theme's function file

### PART ONE - The helping hands

Because we will have repetitive code, lets create filterable helpers

```
/**
 * Return the amount of posts per page, which by default is 11
 */
function wpse_219896_ppp ()
{
    return apply_filters( 'wpse_219896_ppp', 11 );
}

/**
 * Returns the offset to use, which by default is 11
 */
function wpse_219896_offset ()
{
    return apply_filters( 'wpse_219896_offset', 11 );
}
```

We can simply adjust any of these function's output with the following example:

```
add_filter( 'wpse_219895_ppp', function ( $ppp )
{
    return 10;
}
```

This is just done to keep the code maintainable

### PART TWO - `pre_get_posts`

We will now set our posts per page and offsets throught the `pre_get_posts` action

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_home()       // Only target the home page
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
    ) {
        // First set our variables
        $ppp          = wpse_219896_ppp();
        $offset       = wpse_21896_offset();
        $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );

        // Target the first page first
        if ( !$q->is_paged() ) {
            // Add our offset to $ppp
            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', ( $ppp + $offset ) );
        } else { 
            /**
             * Lets target all the paged pages now.
             *
             * Because we are breaking the internal calculation for post offset and pagination,
             * we must manually recalculate and set it
             */
            $paged_offset = $offset + ( ( $current_page -1 ) * $ppp );

            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', $ppp          );
            $q->set( 'offset',         $paged_offset );
        }
    }
});
```

We have now taken care of the posts per page issue, page one will have 22 posts, the rest will have 11

### PART THREE - `found_posts` filter

We now need to adjust for pagination to work correctly

```
add_filter( 'found_posts', function ( $found_posts, $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_home()       // Only target the home page
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
    ) {    
        $offset = wpse_219896_offset();

        // Make sure we have atleat more posts found than the offset
        if ( $offset >= $found_posts ) 
            return $found_posts;

        $found_posts = $found_posts - $offset;
    }
    return $found_posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

### PART FOUR - `the_posts` filter

All we now need to do is to sort the first 11 posts on page one randomly

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', function ( $posts, $q )
{
    if (     $q->is_home()       // Only target the home page
         &&  $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
         && !$q->is_paged()      // Only target page one
    ) {        
        $offset = wpse_219896_offset();

        // Make sure that have more than 11 posts, if not, randomly sort all
        if ( $offset >= $q->post_count ) {
            shuffle( $posts );
            return $posts;
        }

        /**
         * We have more posts than our offset, lets split the array and 
         * randomize the first set of posts
         */
        $array_1 = array_slice( $posts, 0, $offset );
        $array_2 = array_slice( $posts, $offset, '', true );

        // Randomize array_1
        shuffle( $array_1 );

        // Merge the two slices into one array again
        $posts = array_merge( $array_1, $array_2 );
    }
    return $posts;
}, 10, 2 );
```

This should take care of everything.

### ALL TOGETHER NOW

We can simplify this into a plugin. Here is how the final code could look like

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Random posts per page
Plugin URI:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/219896/31545
Description: Different amount of posts  per page with x amount shown randomly
Version:     1.0.0
Author:      Pieter Goosen
Author URI:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31545/pieter-goosen
License:     GPL2
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/

/**
 * Return the amount of posts per page, which by default is 11
 */
function wpse_219896_ppp ()
{
    // Filter the amount of posts per page
    return apply_filters( 'wpse_219896_ppp', 11 );
}

/**
 * Returns the offset to use, which by default is 11
 */
function wpse_219896_offset ()
{
    // Filter the offset of posts
    return apply_filters( 'wpse_219896_offset', 11 );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_home()       // Only target the home page
         && $q->is_main_query() // Only target the main query
    ) {
        // First set our variables
        $ppp          = wpse_219896_ppp();
        $offset       = wpse_219896_offset();
        $current_page = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );

        // Target the first page first
        if ( !$q->is_paged() ) {

            // Add our offset to $ppp
            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', ( $ppp + $offset ) );

            // Filter the_posts to randomize first x amount of posts
            add_filter( 'the_posts', function ( $posts, $q ) use ( $ppp, $offset )
            {
                remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

                if ( !$q->is_main_query() ) 
                    return $posts;

                // Make sure that have more than $offset posts, if not, randomly sort all
                if ( $offset >= count( $q->posts ) ) {
                    shuffle( $posts );
                    return $posts;
                }

                /**
                 * We have more posts than our offset, lets split the array and 
                 * randomize the first set of posts
                 */
                $array_1 = array_slice( $posts, 0, $offset );
                $array_2 = array_slice( $posts, $offset, $ppp, true );

                // Randomize array_1
                shuffle( $array_1 );

                // Merge the two slices into one array again
                $posts = array_merge( $array_1, $array_2 );

                return $posts;
            }, 10, 2 );

        } else { 
            /**
             * Lets target all the paged pages now.
             *
             * Because we are breaking the internal calculation for post offset and pagination,
             * we must manually recalculate and set it
             */
            $paged_offset = $offset + ( ( $current_page -1 ) * $ppp );

            $q->set( 'posts_per_page', $ppp          );
            $q->set( 'offset',         $paged_offset );
        }

        // Filter the found_posts property of the query
        add_filter( 'found_posts', function ( $found_posts, $q ) use ( $offset )
        {
            remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

            if ( !$q->is_main_query() )
                return $found_posts;

            // Make sure we have at leat more posts found than the offset
            if ( $offset >= $found_posts ) 
                return $found_posts;

            return $found_posts - $offset;
        }, 10, 2 );
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems like lot of work :) Thank you very much for comprehensive answer, will try it asap and post my results.

Comment: It actually wasn't that much, you only need to change your loop back to the main loop and then copy the plugin code into a new plugin file and activate the plugin. I hope this works for you

Comment: Just another note. This will be much faster with much less db calls that the code you are using now. Also, pagination might become a big issue with your current code. If I knew this was suppose to be the main query, I would have posted this as an answer to your previous question ;-)

Comment: Any feedback on this issue yet. If my answer worked, please accept my answer, otherwise, please post and accept your own answer