# Display different content on homepage depending on post type

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

In the home page, I have a custom loop for displaying different post type content. I have this loop on my index.php

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
array(
    'post_type' => array('photo', 'video', 'web'), 
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1

)
);
```

Now it displays correctly but I want to include the title from what post type it belongs so that I can link to right page.

for example if I have these items in my home page (as a result of the above loop):

1. Item 1 - [video](http://page-video)
2. Item 2 - [photo](http://page-photo)
3. Item 3 - [web](http://page-web)

Where the links are the page I created that displays those custom post type and the title is the title of the post type (ie video. photo, web).

I have tried this to put inside my loop but it doesn't work.

```
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php
        if ( is_singular( 'photo' ) ) :
           echo "<a href='/photo'>photo</a>";

        elseif ( is_singular( 'video' ) ) :
            echo "<a href='/video'>video</a>";

        elseif ( is_singular( 'web' ) ) :
            echo "<a href='/web'>web</a>";
         endif;
    ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'grid'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: do you really want to just link to /photo, /video or /web ? OR to the actual post permalink with the post title as anchor? as it seems you are asking about post title but then linking to post type.

Comment: It also seems like you *might* be confusing 'post type' with 'post'. Post types don't really have a title as such.. although they do have a label which gives them the name you see in the admin area.

Comment: @majick - I actually want two links. One will be the actual permalink and two, the link to a page where the custom post type are served. Actually, there are no problems with the links. I can just simply echo the links in my ifs. The problem is how it can detect weather it's a video or photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong on many levels here:

- You should not be using a custom query in place of the main query. Rather use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query accordingly. Go back to the main loop and add the following in your functions file or in a custom plugin

  ```
  add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
  {
      if (    $q->is_home()
           && $q->is_main_query()
      ) {
          $q->set( 'post_type',      ['photo', 'video', 'web'] );
          $q->set( 'posts_per_page', -1                        );
      }
  });
  ```
- `is_singular()` is the wrong check here. `is_singular()` checks if you are on a singular post page, so it will always return false on any page that is not a singular post page.

  What you need is `get_post_type()` to get the post type the post belongs to and test against that

  ```
  if ( 'photo' === get_post_type() ) :
     echo "<a href='/photo'>photo</a>";

  elseif ( 'video' === get_post_type() ) :
      echo "<a href='/video'>video</a>";

  elseif ( 'web' === get_post_type() ) :
      echo "<a href='/web'>web</a>";
   endif;
  ```
- Lastly, if you want to link to the archive pages of those post types, you should be using [`get_post_type_archive()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link). Something like the following would work

  ```
  <a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'Photo' ); ?>">Photo</a>
  ```

  instead of `echo "<a href='/photo'>photo</a>"`

### EDIT

From comments, I have done an extensive answer on why not to use custom queries in place of the main query. Feel free to check it out [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545). It should answer quite a few questions for you

Comment: that get_post_type and get_post_type_archive saved me tons. Don't even need to create a page now. Though I have created a template called archive-photo.php and copied the template from my template.

Just want to point out though that pre_get_posts I have one before. I can't remember why but I removed it and changed it to what I have now. BTW, I also tried that one you suggested but I had an error on the line with 4q.

Can you please tell me why this is the right thing to do? Why I should not be using using custom query in place if the main query.

Everything is working with me now.

Comment: Man, that actually worked! Everything now works as you suggested. I swear I had that pre_get_posts before but I'm not sure why I removed it. I think because before I had that page navigation to be displayed so that infinite scroll would work. But I'm not using infinite scroll now. Maybe that's why. But anyway, it worked, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `the_post()` populates the `$post` object variable, so you can use this to make things easier by getting information directly from the `$post` object (and also the post type object):

```
<?php $post_object = array();

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

global $post; $post_type = $post->post_type; // just for clarity

// link to post permalink with post title anchor
echo "<a href='".get_permalink($post->ID)."'>".$post->post_title."</a>";

// to be efficient, only get the post type object if we have not already
if (!isset($post_object[$post_type])) {$post_object[$post_type] = get_post_type_object($post_type);}

// link to post type archive, with post type name as anchor (plural)
echo " (<a href='".get_post_type_archive_link($post_type)."'>".$post_object[$post_type]->labels->name."</a>)";

get_template_part( 'content', 'grid');

endwhile; ?>
```

This should cover all post types now rather than having to add conditions if you ever add more.