# Unable To Get Published posts using query_posts

Tags: query-posts

I'm not sure why this is not working as its a very simple query. It works when i pull all posts including pending, but not when i want to get posts that are only published.

I have a function to get posts. I pass in a bool variable. If its true, i want to pull all posts from a custom post type called books, including ones that are pending/draft. If false i only want the published posts. I see no issues with the code, but it wont work.

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'showposts' => -1,
    'tax_query' =>  array('relation' => 'AND',
        array( 'taxonomy' => 'book-category', 'field' => 'term_id', 'terms' => $termid)
    ),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

if($getpending == true) $args["post_status"] = "any";
else $args["post_status"] = "publish";

$posts = query_posts($args);
```

Comment: `query_posts` modifies WordPress' main loop and is unsuited for pretty much every purpose (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts). There are numerous reasons why `query_posts` wouldn't work as expected in this case. Have you tried using [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) instead?

Comment: this worked. if you want to make this an answer ill give you the vote

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked! Done.

Comment: By the way, if the answer works, you should accept the answer so it doesn't show up as unanswered anymore and people know where to find the working answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you probably shouldn't be using `query_posts`, which modifies WordPress' main loop and is unsuited for pretty much any purpose (read [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) for more info). There are numerous reasons why `query_posts` wouldn't work as expected in this case.

WordPress has two proper approaches to fetching posts: the [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object and the [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function. They work very similarly, with `get_posts` using `WP_Query` internally. However, as one would expect, `WP_Query` allows for more control.

For your case, `get_posts` should work (as there is no further flaw in the code you posted).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the use of `query_posts`, you have another issue, and that is the local use of global `$posts` variable. `$posts` is the global used to hold the main query's posts array. Never use global variables as local variables. Changing global variables is really bad as you break their original and intended values, which is really hard to debug. Instead of using `$posts`, use a custom variable like `$posts_array`.

You most probably also do not need the custom query, but if you do, use `WP_Query` or `get_posts()`, never use `query_posts`. I have discussed everything in detail in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) which also linked to a couple of very important posts.

Just to quickly touch on few other points:

- You should really work on your code's indentation and separation. Your code is a bit hard to read and to debug when you cram so many things into one long line.
- You should be careful setting `post_status` to `any` as this will expose `private` posts to non logged in users, it will also show `future` posts which is not published yet. This might also expose custom statuses that you would not want to show. Rather explicitly set the post statuses you need.

  From `query.php`

  ```
  if ( in_array( 'any', $q_status ) ) {
      foreach ( get_post_stati( array( 'exclude_from_search' => true ) ) as $status ) {
          if ( ! in_array( $status, $q_status ) ) {
              $e_status[] = "$wpdb->posts.post_status <> '$status'";
          }
      }
  } else {
  ```

  Note: `'exclude_from_search' => true` means only `trash` and `auto-draft` are excluded from `any`
- `showposts` have been dropped in favor of `posts_per_page`. It is not depreciated, but if used, it gets converted into `posts_per_page`, so why not use `posts_per_page` from the start

  ```
  if ( isset($q['showposts']) && $q['showposts'] ) {
      $q['showposts'] = (int) $q['showposts'];
      $q['posts_per_page'] = $q['showposts'];
  }
  ```
- You don't need to set arguments to their default values. You can simply leave that out and save extra space and time

If this is a secondary query, you can probably look at something like the following: (*Requires PHP 5.4+*)

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'book',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'          => 'ASC'
    'tax_query'      =>  [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'book-category', 
            'terms'    => $termid
        ]
    ],
];

if ( true == $getpending ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // This can be adjusted to match core
        $args["post_status"] = ['publish', 'private', 'draft'];
    } else {
        $args["post_status"] = ['publish', 'draft'];
    }
}

$posts_array = WP_Query( $args );
```

I do believe, looking at the `terms` value in you `tax_query`, this might be the main query. If so, you should really look into `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom query instead https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query as using query_posts() https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts  isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes.

Replace your code with this one:

```
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'book',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' =>  array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array( 'taxonomy' => 'book-category', 
                                        'field' => 'term_id', 
                                        'terms' => $termid
                                        )
        ),
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    if($getpending == true) 
        $args["post_status"] = "any";
        else 
        $args["post_status"] = "publish";

    $ustom_posts = new WP_Query($args);
    if($ustom_posts->have_posts())
        {
            $ustom_posts->the_post();

            //echo $post->post_title;   
            //your further code
        }
```