# pre_get_posts variables

Tags: pre-get-posts

Following up on [Adding arg to search results page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/222515/adding-arg-to-search-results-page), I want to show future posts in categories but not on the home page.

This code works:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) {
if (    !is_admin()
     && !is_feed()
     && $q->is_main_query() 
) {
    $q->set( 'post_status', ['publish', 'future'] );
}
});
```

but shows future posts on home page.

I tried adding `&& !is_home()` but it doesn't work - future posts no longer show anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The logic inside the `is_home` function relies on the main query, but by definition that query hasn't happened yet as you're still in the `pre_get_posts` filter.

Instead, consider `$q->is_home()`. The same goes for `is_feed()` `$q->is_feed()`