# Custom Taxonomy: show one or the other term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tax-query

I have registered a taxonomy called `location` - I have then created a taxonomy file called `taxonomy-location.php` which is fine and returns all the terms within that taxonomy.

Say I have a 2 terms one called London and the other called Birmingham - I am able to do this:

```
$property = array( 'post_type' => 'properties');
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => $property,
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'london'
        ),
    ),
));
```

but when I head to the Birmingham term it only returns results for London - which is expected because I set the term to London for all of them.

My question is how do I make it only return only that taxonomy term?

**Extra Info**: I am registering my Custom Post Type and Taxonomies inside a Plugin

Comment: The main query will contain posts associated to whatever term you are viewing, you don't have to query for them yourself.

Comment: @Milo Hmmm... that's strange for mine if I went to example.com/location/London it would display all the Birmingham ones aswell

Comment: You should be replacing the main query with a custom one, ever. It create much more issues than solving one. You should take your time and read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Yh I have gotten rid of that now and made an `archive-property.php` page and that stops me from altering the query, this is like my first time making a big theme with a lot of different custom post type so I'm still learning as I go along :) :D