# Is `query_posts` really slower than secondary query?

Tags: loop, query, query-posts

I know the main query is fast, since it gets data after parsing the URL and after `WP_Query` has been instantiated. We are in OO PHP.

But is `query_posts` really slower than some secondary query that happens in a template for instance with `get_posts`, or native that you call with

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: `query_posts` users `WP_Query` so it is a secondary query. If you need to use `query_posts` then use the `pre_get_posts` hook instead which is much faster than a new database call. [See the most famous answer in WPSE history!](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/7355)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: I know, all guys use `WP_Query`, this is the big boss. I just wanted to show there may not be a "big red button" bellow `query_posts` where it reads "Don't press here".

Comment: "We are in OO PHP" lol wut? How does that mean "fast"?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee the main query also uses `WP_Query`, so is it also a secondary query ;-)

Comment: The "Don't use `query_posts()`" mantra isn't (just) because it's slow; it's because it overwrites the main query and can cause unexpected results. [See this answer for more details.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/16121)

Answer (score 7):

You ask:

> is query_posts really slower than some secondary query...

The fact is that if you're calling `query_posts()` from a theme then **it already is a secondary query**. WordPress has already queried the database once to get a certain page then it hits your `query_posts()` function and queries the database *again* creating a *second query* and overwriting the original request / data.

From a speed perspective you're not going to notice any difference. The `query_posts()` functions uses `WP_Query()` and takes microseconds to overwrite some global variables. The biggest overhead will come from you having to normalize your data and make up for any niche issues with pagination.

Simply put, it's all around inefficient. <strike>So, while there may not be a "big red button" that says "Don't press here!" it's pretty much implied that it shouldn't be pressed.</strike> It's not big and red but [The Codex specifically states](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes.

If you want to be efficient and need to override the main query - use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) which will modify the query parameters before it calls it from the database which saves an entire database call ( in that we don't need a secondary query ).

Comment: I just read this codex, and there is one bug where it reads : "Note: The pre_get_posts action doesn't work for Page requests." This is actually not correct, and `pre_get_posts` can work with any posts, pages posts, or custom post types. It cannot work with with single pages.

Comment: Also, query_posts() can "outright fail in some circumstances, (especially often when dealing with posts pagination)" (from the famous WPSE post)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I like your answer, you are saying we will not note big difference. +1

Comment: @prosti As far as I know `pre_get_posts` does work with single pages and  *almost* any WordPress request. I've removed that portion from The Codex as I can see it's confusing ( and may be an old documentation ). For some reason I still feel the need to discourage you from using `query_posts()` though in favor of `pre_get_posts` as that filter is ultimately faster...

Answer (score 3):

In general,

- the query performed on the homepage,
- `query_posts( 'posts_per_page=get_option( 'posts_per_page' )` and
- `$q = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=get_option( 'posts_per_page' )`

should have the same exact performance with very very little to no difference between them as all of the above are exactly the same by default (*that is, have the same query arguments by default*). This is because all of these queries uses the `WP_Query` class to run build and run db queries to return the queried posts. `get_posts()` is a bit faster although it also uses `WP_Query`. The big difference is that `get_posts` passes `no_found_rows=true` to `WP_Query` which legally breaks pagination.

What is true, the main query (*primary query*) runs on each and every page load according to the exact page being loaded. Removing the main loop and replacing it with a secondary query (*either `query_posts()`, `WP_Query` or `get_posts()`*) is what is referred to as making the page slow. This is because you are doing the same work twice. As I said, the main query runs regardless, so you have already queried the db for posts, and replacing the main loop with a secondary query queries the db again.

Apart from issues created with pagination and other crappy issues, this is why one should **never** replace the main loop from the main query with a secondary one. I have done an extensive post on this which you can read [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545). To alter the main query, always use `pre_get_posts` as it alters the query vars before the `WP_Query` class builds and runs the SQL query. There are also other filters (*post clause filters*) available in `WP_Query` which you can use to directly alter the SQL query

What makes `query_posts` bad is that it alters the main query object on which many functions rely as `query_posts` does the following

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query()
```

and it also alters the conditional tags. For a full explanation, you can read my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/191934/31545). A normal `WP_Query` does not do that

Comment: ***should have the same exact performance with very very little to no difference between them as all of the above are exactly the same by default** this is actually what I thought about the performance, but needed someone experienced to confirm me that. WE can also add in your answer "for the same query arguments".

Comment: True, I have added that as part of my answer. ;-)

Comment: Just a note, you can always file an edit and add constructive info to any post as you see fit. I will always accept such edits. Best part is, you can 2 rep points which helps you later on ;-)