# Problem with older entries in homepage

Tags: pagination, homepage

When I click on "older entries" in my home page, it goes to a second link but it shows the same posts. I think I need to modify something in the `index.php`, this is the full code section that I think I need to modify:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="post_content">
        <div class="home_posts">
            <?php
                $args2 = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 2),
                );
                $query = new WP_Query( $args2 );
                if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                        echo '<div class="grid_post">
                                <h3><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>';
                        $type = get_post_meta($post->ID,'page_featured_type',true);
                        switch ($type) {
                            case 'youtube':
                                echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'page_video_id', true ).'?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                                break;
                            case 'vimeo':
                                echo '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'page_video_id', true ).'?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=03b3fc" width="500" height="338" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
                                break;
                            default:
                                echo '<div class="grid_post_img">
                                            <a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'</a>
                                        </div>';
                                break;
                        }
                        echo '<div class="grid_home_posts">
                                    <p>'.dess_get_excerpt(120).'</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            ';
                    endwhile;
            ?>
    </div>
    <?php
        echo '<div class="load_more_content"><div class="load_more_text">';
                ob_start();
                    next_posts_link('LOAD MORE',$query->max_num_pages);
                    $buffer = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                if(!empty($buffer)) echo $buffer;
            echo'</div></div>';                 
        $max_pages = $query->max_num_pages;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;
    ?>
    <span id="max-pages" style="display:none"><?php echo $max_pages ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Could it be here:

```
<?php


$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args2 );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            echo '<div class="grid_post">
```

This is the URL to "Older entries": http://www.wha2wear.com/page/2/ that shows the same content as the homepage. Also, I don't really see that "Older entries" is written somewhere in the code..

Also, in the actual page, Front Page page, there is this code

```
[posts-for-page order_by ='date' hide_images='false' num='11' read_more='
Read More »' show_full_posts='false' use_wp_excerpt='true' strip_html='true' hide_post_content='false' show_meta='false' force_image_height='200' force_image_width='250']
```

**I have the feeling that this code has higher priority than the php, so the homepage does what it says there?**

Comment: Try changing your

`'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 2),`

to

`'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`

IT seems that the issue might because of the  get_query_var('paged') you have by default set it up as 2. Try changing the value from `2 to 1` then that should solve your pagination issue

Comment: Do not use a custom query, that is your biggest issue here.

Comment: thank you, but I still have the same problem, it goes to http://www.wha2wear.com/page/2/ and same posts appear :( what else would be? thanks a lot

Comment: Hi guys, I've edited my question because I think I need to modify the full php query (the second bit of code), could you tell me how it should be, please?

Comment: As I stated, do not use a custom query, see [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

Comment: Thank you, but as I mention, I'm not an expert on php so I'm not sure how to write what I want to do... also, there it doesn't say anything about the pagination?

Comment: @Wha2wear WordPress's default pagination links modify the "main query" to display a different group of it's results. When you use `$query = new WP_Query()` and proceed to use methods on the `$query` object, you are completely ignoring the main query - so two queries are always being ran when you only need one, and the pagination links are modifying a result-set that you never use. Instead of creating a second query with `new WP_Query()` or `query_posts()`, PieterGoosen is suggesting that you modify the main query to fit your needs - the method of doing so is detailed in his linked answer.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand. I've replaced the php code and write the code from the link but same thing happens...does anyone know how to write the correct code, please? As I said, I have a very basic knowledge on PHP, I just understand what it does, but I'm not able to create anything. If you understand, could tell me how it is?

Comment: I don't know that the first code does, but the second code doesn't change the behavior :(

Comment: can you add the URL of the "older posts" link to the question in case the problem is there (some kind of mismatched query)

Comment: @majick just did it, at the end for the question (http://www.wha2wear.com/page/2/) thank you!!

Comment: suggest you add this to your template somewhere `<?php echo '<!--'; print_r(get_queried_object()); echo '-->'; ?>` to help debug the query request.

Comment: @majick thank you, I put it at the end of index.php, is that ok?

Comment: it should work but I am not seeing anything from it, try putting it at the start perhaps and clearing the cache if you have one on. also check my possible answer.

Comment: actually are you sure you are editing the correct template file? if that is not showing up it is unlikely... besides in your question the code has a div container `home_posts` that does not exist in your page source. possibly you need to be editing `front-page.php` or `home.php`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with default query and use like this

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; }

$args = array(
'post_type'         => 'post',
'posts_per_page'    => 6,
'paged'             => $paged,
);

query_posts($args); while (have_posts()): the_post();

// do something

endwhile;
```

See here more details about Adding the "paged" parameter to a query

https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22paged.22_parameter_to_a_query

Comment: thank you, but I put that but still see the same. Also, the homepage page in wordpress have some code. I'll edit my question in case it's something to do with that

Comment: please, have a look to the info I added to my question.

Comment: When you are using query_posts then did you change next_posts_link() parameter ?

anyway you can try just next_posts_link(''LOAD MORE') without using $max_pages parameter or next_posts_link(''LOAD MORE', 6) static next_posts_link(''LOAD MORE') parameter .

Once a time I faced this problem and then I solved this with [front-page-wp-query-pagination-issue-repeating-posts-next_posts_link-help](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/front-page-wp-query-pagination-issue-repeating-posts-next_posts_link-help)  this posts solution that I already share with you :)

Comment: thank you. where should I put the next_posts_link(''LOAD MORE', 6) parameter? Is that inside the query where you put // do something?

Comment: It will work inside and outside as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If the posts are being displayed via a static front page (they seem to be?) then you need to use the query parameter `page` not `paged`. You could try this:

```
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('page') ? get_query_var('page') : 1),
);
```

As mentioned on: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Edit: note however the `paged` parameter is still set in the query array but the `page` query_var is used. This from example at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: thanks a lot, I cleared the cache and I put the php to debug at the beginning. I also put the the code from your answer, but I don't know why I still see the same (including the 10 posts as before) and I delete my browser cache too. What do you see?

Comment: I see nothing, it surely must be the wrong file you are editing, `index.php` is a fallback when no other template is being used.

Comment: please, have a look to the info I added to my question.

Comment: looks like you are onto it with ajax load more... that is a better way to go here... since you can customize the repeater template and the replace the existing shortcode you have with the ALM shortcode to show the initial posts.

Comment: I know, that's what I did, but I'd like also to delete the "Older entries" text. Do you know how I can find it?

Comment: it's the call to `next_post_link()` in the template that is giving that, you would still need to find the right template where that is being used.

Answer (score 0):

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
    'orderby'=> 'id',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'paged'=>$paged
  );
global $wp_query;
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( have_posts() ) : 

    while ( have_posts() ):
       the_post();  


      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format());
      endif;

      $count++;
      endwhile;
      // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
    else :
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif;

         $nav = get_the_posts_pagination( array(
            'mid_size'           => 4,
            'prev_text'          => __( '&laquo;', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'next_text'          => __( '&raquo;', 'twentysixteen' ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( '', 'twentysixteen' ) . ' </span>',
            'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Post Navigation' )
        ) );

         $nav = str_replace('<h2 class="screen-reader-text">Post Navigation</h2>', '', $nav);
         echo $nav;

    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $original_query;
    wp_reset_postdata();$wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $original_query;
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

this is how it will work, you need to update WP_Query, not to use another object, it wouldn't work with pagination.