# Is dynamic URL possible in Wordpress

Tags: urls

I know the title seems little bit confusing, but what I am looking for is something possible in symfony or ror. I have a page with this URL: `http://mydomain.com/job/`. Now I want this URL structure `http://mydomain.com/job/php-developer/45`, `http://mydomain.com/job/java-developer/46`. Now the parameters after `/job/` are dynamic, and they are not any page or post, they fall under a page `job`

Is this possible in Wordpress?

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

Ok as per @Gioia's answer I updated my code.

Below is my code:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "job_title"; 
    $aVars[] = "job_id"; 
    return $aVars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'add_rules' );  
function add_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^/job/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=13338&job_title=$matches[1]&job_id=$matches[2]','top');
}
```

So now this is throwing me 404 page when I try this URL `http://mydomain.com/job/php-dev/45`. But when I try this URL `http://mydomain.com/index.php?page_id=13338&job_title=php-dev&job_id=45` it works.

Comment: You could achieve `/job/job-title/` by using a custom post type and possibly `/45` by doing a custom structure with your post type.

Comment: my URL are dynamic, `/job/php-developer/45` , `/job/java-developer/46` etc

Comment: What is the purpose of 45 / 46? Are these counters? What do they represent to make them dynamic?

Comment: My goal is to achieve this URL `http://mydomain.com/job/?title=php-developer&job_id=45`, but to make this URL SEO friendly, I want something like this `http://mydomain.com/job/php-developer/45`

Comment: Where Job ID is a meta value of some kind? [That is not a simple task.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99378/rewrite-custom-post-type-urls-adding-meta-box-values)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thats some ID stored inside some table

Comment: Hey, don't forget to update your question to remove the faulty / :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not completely sure I understand what you mean with that the parameters fall under a page job, but if you mean that different contents are loaded on the same page using javascript / ajax, you could use https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ to generate the corresponding url for each state. Difficult to say more about how you could implement this without knowing more about what you are trying to do.

---

### UPDATE

I think you should use custom rewrite rules. That is what wordpress uses to create the nice urls, and it has an API to add your own.

First you need to add the tags you need to track, in your case title and job_id. Actually you should probably change title to something like job_title, I am not completely sure title would create a problem, but since it is something in wordpress, it is better to be on the safe side.

I used the following code, you need to add it to your function.php, in your theme.

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "job_title"; 
    $aVars[] = "job_id"; 
    return $aVars;
}
```

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag

Then you add the rewrite rule, also in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_rules' );  
function add_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^job/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&job_title=$matches[1]&job_id=$matches[2]','top');
}
```

You should replace the page_id by the id of the job page
More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule.

Once you have saved the file, you need to go to settings -> permalinks and simply save without changing anything. That will make sure your settings are correctly loaded.

You can install the plugin rewrite inspector to see all the rewrite rules applied and check that yours are present.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/

You can install the plugin debug bar to inspect the page and see what rewrite rule is being applied to the page:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/

And here you have more info on rewrite rules in general:
http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

---

UPDATE 2

To retrieve the parameters:

```
if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['job_title'])) {
    $job_title = urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['job_title']);?>
<?php }
```

Comment: My goal is to achieve this URL `http://mydomain.com/job/?title=php-developer&job_id=45`, but to make this URL SEO friendly, I want something like this `http://mydomain.com/job/php-developer/45`

Comment: You could use custom rewrite rules:

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried your code, but its throwing 404 page, please check my edit above in question.

Comment: Hi, I just tried the code and it worked for me. First, check that you have changed the id of the page that came in the code (?page_id=12) to the id of the job page (you can see what is the id of the page when you are in the edit page, it is part of the url: post.php?post=6&action=edit, 6 is the id of the page). Also make sure after every change to go to the permalinks settings page and saving.

Comment: I changed the page ID as per mine, if I hit this URL `index.php?page_id=13338&job_title=$matches[1]&job_id=$matches[2]` it is working, but with the custom URL its not. Do I need to add `add_rewrite_tag`? or some htaccess modifications?

Comment: Just to be sure, you went to the permalinks settings and saved?

Comment: Yes I did a save in permalinks, my permalinks structure is in this way `/%postname%/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15205/discussion-between-gioia-fueter-and-ntechi).