# Dynamic URL with rewrite rule not working

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to update my link from this: https://dev.brunchwork.com/next-event/?eb_event_id=106098978902
To this: [https://dev.brunchwork.com/next-event/[guest_name_here]/[event_id_here]](https://dev.brunchwork.com/next-event/%5Bguest_name_here%5D/%5Bevent_id_here%5D)

Following this [discussion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149985/is-dynamic-url-possible-in-wordpress), I was able to come up with this code:

In my functions.php:

```
/*rewrite rule*/
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^next-event/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=69&guest_name=$matches[1]&event_id=$matches[2]','top');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);


add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "guest_name";
    $aVars[] = "event_id";
    return $aVars;
}
/*end rewrite rule*/
```

In my next-event page:

```
/*
Template Name: Single Event Template (updated)
*/

get_header();

global $wp_query;

$guest_name = $wp_query->query_vars['guest_name'];
$test_eb_event_id = $wp_query->query_vars['event_id'];

echo $guest_name;
echo $test_eb_event_id;
```

When I try to test the URL, the rewrite is not working. I also clicked the save button in the permalinks page to apply the changes.

So when I enter: `https://dev.brunchwork.com/index.php?page_id=69&guest_name=test&event_id=123`

I get `https://dev.brunchwork.com/next-event/?guest_name=test&event_id=123`

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with my code. Maybe it was not refreshed instantly so the changes did not propagate right away.